# Regex (grep) for multi-line search needed

Tags: regex, linux, cygwin, grep

I'm running a `grep` to find any *.sql file that has the word `select` followed by the word `customerName` followed by the word `from`. This select statement can span many lines and can contain tabs and newlines.

I've tried a few variations on the following:

```bash
$ grep -liIr --include="*.sql" --exclude-dir="\.svn*" --regexp="select[a-zA-Z0-
9+\n\r]*customerName[a-zA-Z0-9+\n\r]*from"
```

This, however, just runs forever. Can anyone help me with the correct syntax please?

Comment: The grep you've indicated here runs forever because you have not specified any files to search at the end of the command...  

The '--include' is a filter of the files named and doesn't actually provide you any files to be filtered.

Answer (score 640, accepted):

Without the need to install the grep variant `pcregrep`, you can do a multiline search with grep.

```bash
$ grep -Pzo "(?s)^(\s*)\N*main.*?{.*?^\1}" *.c
```

Explanation:

`-P` activate [perl-regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) for grep (a powerful extension of regular expressions)

`-z` Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. That is, grep knows where the ends of the lines are, but sees the input as one big line.  Beware this also adds a trailing NUL char if used with `-o`, see comments.

`-o` print only matching. Because we're using `-z`, the whole file is like a single big line, so if there is a match, the entire file would be printed; this way it won't do that.

In regexp:

`(?s)` activate `PCRE_DOTALL`, which means that `.` finds any character or newline

`\N` find anything except newline, even with `PCRE_DOTALL` activated

`.*?` find `.` in non-greedy mode, that is, stops as soon as possible.

`^` find start of line

`\1` backreference to the first group (`\s*`). This is a try to find the same indentation of method.

As you can imagine, this search prints the main method in a C (`*.c`) source file.

Comment: /bin/grep: The -P and -z options cannot be combined

Comment: /bin/grep: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u

Comment: I'm using **GNU grep 2.6.3**, bundled in **Ubuntu 11.04** and it does, what's your version @Oli ?

Comment: gnu grep version 2.5.4, using the last ubuntu LTS (lucid, 10.04)

Comment: -zo was enough for my multi-line needs, thanks! (upvoted.)

Comment: I needed to use "grep -PZo", capital z, on Gentoo (linux).

Comment: "As you can imagine, this search prints the main method in a C (*.c) source file." ...  I dare to say it out loud : if you say so ... :)

Comment: Do you have a solution that works for big files that can't be read into memory?

Comment: Oli, on GNU grep 2.14 (distr with ubuntu 13.04x64),  you CAN use -z and -P together, in fact you probably wont get what you want unless you include -Pzo, usually (and start regex with (?s)) -- anyone that uses perl regex often should read (and keep a printout of) the manpage "perlreref" which is a great short text reference to many of the regular expressions you might need, a "cheat sheet" if you will...

Comment: @albfan, my version of GNU grep (2.5.1) supports multiline search using `(?s)` but without the need to supply `-z` to identify NUL as the line terminator. Is there a specific reason you use `-z` here?

Comment: `-P` worked for me without `-zo`. So it seems it works with one of the other, according comments.

Comment: I recommend ''**grep -Pazo**'' instead of the unsafer ''-Pzo''. Explanation: the -z switch on non-ASCII files _may_ trigger grep's "binary data" behaviour which changes the return values. Switch ''-a | --text'' prevents that.

Comment: How would you loop through the results of these?

Comment: @Saichovsky not exactly loop, but you can pipe to less and move around: `grep <whatever> --color=always | less -R`.

`gg` go to end, `G` go to init, `/` search, `n` go to next result...

Comment: FYI, on OS X, the system default `grep` is BSD based and not the GNU version. As a result, PCRE (the `-P` switch) is sadly unsupported.

Comment: You mentioned that -z switch converts new lines into null characters. If you have to search near the new line, would you search for null characters or [[:space:]] or new line?

Comment: +1 for showing the [embedded modifier trick](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Embedding-comments-and-modifiers-in-a-regular-expression), e.g., `(?s)`!

Comment: If you are looking for a multiline grep, use `pcregrep`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep).

Comment: GNU grep need to be installed manually. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-osx

Comment: -z is not for `substituting newline with null char`, but `Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline` according to the manual.

Comment: pipe the result to `tr '\0' '\n'` if you need the matches on separate lines!

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is *still* experimental. That and of course it's not portable (though that doesn't have to matter). CentOS man page refers to it being 'highly experimental'; Fedora 29 says only 'experimental'. Would be nice though if it was standardised.

Comment: `-z`, aka. `--null-data` will output an extra NUL(\x00) character for each match. This might be an unwanted side-effect for some use cases.

Comment: @youfu, any idea on how to prevent adding extra NUL(\x00) character an the end of a match? P.S. `$ grep --version`: `grep (GNU grep) 3.0 - Packaged by Cygwin (3.0-2)`.

Comment: As already noted, `-z` makes `grep` end its output with a `\x00`;  other than `tr`anslating it, you may alternatively pipe through `head --bytes=-1` to truncate the null byte.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for posting.  Btw for mac just use `brew install grep` then use this with `ggrep` .

Comment: `grep -Pz '\x00' file.txt` returns exit code `1`. Answer says that `-z` option replaces newlines with null bytes. This is false. Otherwise this would return an exit code of `0` (success) for any file with more than one line.

Comment: I've tried this with GNU grep 3.3 and it simply does not seem to work. `^` doesn't match the beginnings of lines if `-z` is passed.

Comment: use pcre2grep to avoid "grep: memory exhausted"

Answer (score 217):

I am not very good in grep. But your problem can be solved using [AWK](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html) command.
Just see

```bash
awk '/select/,/from/' *.sql
```

The above code will result from first occurence of `select` till first sequence of `from`. Now you need to verify whether returned statements are having `customername` or not. For this you can pipe the result. And can use awk or grep again.

Comment: Awesome simple solution. Note: The comma is used as a separator in AWK _range pattern_. See full explanation in [section 7.1.3 Specifying Record Ranges with Patterns of AWK user guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Ranges)

Comment: For completeness: this works with (simpler) sed too: `sed -n '/select/,/from/p' whatever.sql`

Answer (score 8):

Your fundamental problem is that `grep` works one line at a time - so it cannot find a SELECT statement spread across lines.

Your second problem is that the regex you are using doesn't deal with the complexity of what can appear between SELECT and FROM - in particular, it omits commas, full stops (periods) and blanks, but also quotes and anything that can be inside a quoted string.

I would likely go with a Perl-based solution, having Perl read 'paragraphs' at a time and applying a regex to that.  The downside is having to deal with the recursive search - there are modules to do that, of course, including the core module [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html).

In outline, for a single file:

```
$/ = "\n\n";    # Paragraphs

while (<>)
{
     if ($_ =~ m/SELECT.*customerName.*FROM/mi)
     {
         printf file name
         go to next file
     }
}
```

That needs to be wrapped into a sub that is then invoked by the methods of File::Find.

Comment: Grep does not work one line a time. It searches through the entire corpus for matches, and only when it finds a match does it go back to consider whether a newline is in the middle. That way, it doesn't have to scan through the corpus looking for new lines (which would slow it down significantly)

Comment: @MrBones: there's a chance that a modern implementaton of `grep` does as you say using `mmap()` to read the file into memory, but its mode of operation is defined by the POSIX specification for [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) and it decidedly works in terms of lines. I'm not convinced though; if the file is multiple gigabytes, there is no need to memory map it all when you can simply read in a few kilobytes at a time (most files with lines have lines that are less than kilobytes long).  Then there's JSON files, of course, but they're exceptional.

Comment: It works in terms of lines, but it doesn't work one line at a time. There's not a loop doing some kind of `(for line in lines: doesMatch(line))`. It's more obvious when considering fgrep (fixed strings), and how boyer-moore works. mmap isn't really relevant

Comment: that's a lot of problems on top of the original problem, plus the problem of the regex!

Comment: @Squidly Whether or not that's true does not change the fact that it considers a line at a time. How something is programmed doesn't equate to how it works does it?

Comment: Grep works on one line at a time.  If you use -z then its "one line" is interpreted as the whole file since there aren't any NUL's in there for it to find to delineate.