# Why can't i match the pattern in this case?

Tags: bash

```
 <tr>$
                                  <td nowrap valign="top" class="table_1row"><a name="d071301" id="d071301"></a>13-Jul-2011</td>$
```

i would like to match `tr>$ <td nowrap valign`, but when i try

```
grep -c "tr>\n<td nowrap valign" test.html
```

then i also tried

```
grep -c "tr>\n\s*<td nowrap valign" test.html
```

both of them find nothing. What error here?

One more question, can i add a character ^M into a html file by using sed???thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` only does single line searches.  [Another source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed/3717838#3717838)

To recap on some comments, `sed` does multiline searches and you can address the carriage return in sed syntax with `\r`

Comment: please spend a few second. i would like to delete the line which has the sixth <ul> occurance. i google the way of doing it and sed -i '/^<ul>$/ d/6' file .However, it turn out a sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after command error?

Answer (score 0):

To add your control character, add the actual character: Type Ctrl+V, Ctrl+M.

sed will treat the control character just like a normal character.

Comment: î would like to use sed to add so , is it sed -i 's/somthing/Ctrl+V/g' file ??

Comment: No, you actually type (on your keyboard) Ctrl+V, and then Ctrl+M. This is how you produce control characters in bash. They'll show up as ^M on screen but will be one character long. Your sed would look something like this: `sed -i 's/something/^M/g' file`.

Comment: i can just using ^M in sed? but will it confused with actual text ^M?

Comment: Nope, sed would interpret that as two characters: a carat (^) and a capital M. If you use the control character, however, sed will see that as a single character.

Comment: I could very well be mistaken, but isn't ^M representing a carriage return, which you can just use `\r`?

Comment: please spend a few second
i would like to delete the line which has the sixth <ul> occurance 
i google the way of doing it and
sed -i '/^<ul>$/ d/6' file
However, it turn out a sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after command error?

Comment: @Andy, you're correct. `^M` is equivalent to `\r`, which is probably what @hk should be using since it's more clear.

Comment: You should open another question up about this and accept an answer (if you feel it is acceptable) for this one

Comment: alright but in the above case which one would match ? grep -c "tr>\n<td nowrap valign" test.html or grep -c "tr>\n\s*<td nowrap valign" test.html

Comment: neither, grep isn't going to look at more than one line, so when you put a new line in the middle of your regex, it is never going to match.