# Is there a way to put the following logic into a grep command?

Tags: linux, shell, text, csv, grep

For example suppose I have the following piece of data

```
ABC,3,4
,,ExtraInfo
,,MoreInfo
XYZ,6,7
,,XyzInfo
,,MoreXyz
ABC,1,2
,,ABCInfo
,,MoreABC
```

It's trivial to get grep to extract the ABC lines. However if I want to also grab the following lines to produce this output

```
ABC,3,4
,,ExtraInfo
,,MoreInfo
ABC,1,2
,,ABCInfo
,,MoreABC
```

Can this be done using grep and standard shell scripting?

Edit: Just to clarify there could be a variable number of lines in between. The logic would be to keep printing while the first column of the CSV is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep -A 2 {Your regex}` will output the two lines following the found strings.

*Update:*
Since you specified that it could be any number of lines, this would not be possible as grep focuses on matching on a single line see the following questions:

- [How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file-use-pcregrep)
- [Regex (grep) for multi-line search needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed)
- [Why can't i match the pattern in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756784/why-cant-i-match-the-pattern-in-this-case)
- [Selecting text spanning multiple lines using grep and regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223119/selecting-text-spanning-multiple-lines-using-grep-and-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, although a bit hackity due to the grep at the end of the pipeline to mute out anything that does not start with 'A' or ',':

```
$ sed -n '/^ABC/,/^[^,]/p' yourfile.txt| grep -v '^[^A,]'
```

Edit: A less hackity way is to use awk:

```
$ awk '/^ABC/ { want = 1 } !/^ABC/ && !/^,/ { want = 0 } { if (want) print }' f.txt
```

You can understand what it does if you read out loud the pattern and the thing in the braces.

Comment: even less hackity awk: `awk -F, '$1 != "" {want = $1 == "ABC"} want {print}'`

Answer (score 1):

The manpage has explanations for the options, of which you want to look at -A under [Context Line Control](http://www.gnu.org/s/grep/manual/grep.html#Context-Line-Control).