# Selecting text spanning multiple lines using grep and regular expressions

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to match lines with the *xs:element* tag that only contain *minOccurs*. As seen below some of them contain both search criteria on one line, some of them span multiple lines. Is there a way of selecting them using grep and regular expressions.

```
<xs:element name="shipto">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" 
               minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The correct output should be as follows:

```
<xs:element name="city" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="country" 
               minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not using a parser for this rather than regex?

Comment: He's not trying to parse XML, he's trying to match XML text. These are two different tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming well-formed XML (i.e. no un-escaped > inside attributes) then you can probably do this:

```
<xs:element[^>]+?\sminOccurs\s*=[^>]+>
```

However, I'm not sure this will work with grep, since grep matches individual lines, so you may need to write a perl script or something to do it.

*(Note, if you somehow have attributes which contain the value `sminOccurs=` then you'd need to get cleverer, but since this appears to be address data, I'm assuming that's unlikely, and manually removing any that happen to occur isn't going to be a problem.)*

Comment: This worked for the element that was broken up between two lines using grep -P. But didn't match the first line where minOccurs was on the same line as the xs:element.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what's up with that. Since `-P` uses Perl then all that syntax is definitely valid, and should work. :/ I guess you could try `<xs:element\s+\S+\s+minOccurs\S+\s+[^>]+>` but that may be being too restrictive.

Comment: Phew! You had me baffled for a while. :)

Comment: Peter, how would a regex look where I was match an xs:element that *didn't* have *minOccurs* in it?

Comment: This should do it: `<xs:element(?:(?!\sminOccurs\s*=)[^>])+>`

Comment: Thanks! I also posted the question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223119/selecting-text-spanning-multiple-lines-using-grep-and-regular-expressions/7223154#7223154

Comment: Also use the -Pzo flags for grep. More explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed/7167115#7167115

Answer (score 2):

I advise against parsing XML using regex. It is too complicated to match tags with end-tags in a robust way.

There is a command line tool "xpath" using XML::XPath in Perl (Ubuntu package libxml-xpath-perl). Example:

```
xpath -e '//*[@minOccurs=1]' file.xml
```

Output

```
-- NODE --
<xs:element name="city" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
-- NODE --
<xs:element name="country" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
```