# GREP - "dot match newline" option?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Example:

```
...
Line
some text
other text
10
...
```

Is it possible to tell GREP `^Line.*?^10$` so that dot matches also newline and I get this output:

```
Line
some text
other text
10
```

If not, is there some Linux CLI tool that can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/3717772/576875

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your intend is to output lines between, and including, `Line` and `10`, I suggest to use awk:

```
awk '/^Line$/,/^10$/' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -rn '/^Line$/,/^10$/p' filename
```