# Regex (in Linux) over multple lines in which you only care about the beginning and ending words

Tags: regex, linux

Suppose I had a file that had a lot of text in it.  At some point I wanted to search for the following text in that file.  But not exactly this text.  In fact I wanted to find any text "paragraph," that could be multiple lines, that started with a line that started with "service surfaceflinger" then had a line that ended with "zygote".

What's the Linux regex for a search that would encounter this?

```
service surfaceflinger /system/bin/surfaceflinger

  class main

   user system

   group graphics

   onrestart restart zygote
```

Comment: check out this thread
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed

Comment: Are "paragraphs" separated by spaces? So "service surfaceflinger"  will always be at the beginning?

Comment: My first down vote.  Well in regex it's difficult to enumerate all the  patterns that you've tried.  I tried 10 or 12 different regexs.  Maybe this is a dup.  For that I'm sorry.

Comment: By "paragraph" I just mean that there is a line that starts with "service surfaceflinger" then somewhere below it is a line that ends with "zygote". I want find all text between those occurrences including those occurrences. The first occurrence of a line ending with "zygote" after a line beginning with "surface..." would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [**`awk`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
awk '/^service surfaceflinger/,/zygote$/' file_with_a_lot_of_text
```

Using [**`sed`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html):

```
sed -n '/^service surfaceflinger/,/zygote$/p' file_with_a_lot_of_text
```

Recommended reading: [sed & awk](http://tinyurl.com/SedAwkBook).

Comment: I used the "sed" version of this answer and it worked for finding the text. Now suppose I wanted to add a line after that text that simply said "disabled"? I tried 
sed -n '/^service surfaceflinger/,/zygote$/a\ 
disabled' filename
but that added the line with the string "disabled" in between every line of that text, not just after the last line of that text.

Comment: @JoeC: Then that is a different question and should be asked as such!

Comment: Well I already got a down-vote for asking about this stuff, so I was trying to keep a low profile.  But anyway thx for the tip.  ;)

Comment: @JoeC: The down-vote wasn't from me, but I suspect it wasn't "for asking about this stuff". If you hover over the ▼ next to the question, you'll see, "This question does not show any research effort". If you included your attempt with `/a`, like you did in your email, you'd be less likely to be down-voted.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
(?ms)^service surfaceflinger.*?zygote$
```

where:

`(?ms)` turns on multi-line and dot-all mode (`.` matches any character)

`^` matches start of line

`.*?` matches any number of characters lazily

`$` matches end of line