# Python-issued grep regex, match this pattern

Tags: python, terminal, grep

I can't figure out how to match this pattern via a grep command I am issuing via Python.

I want to match a string in the form of

`foo.bar([anything including newlines, spaces, tabs])` .

I am trying with:

```
regex = " foo.bar(.*) "
bashCommand = "grep"+" -r -h"+regex+baseDir
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
requires = process.communicate()[0]
```

But I fail to match this string

```
dojo.require("abc.def"


    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep works line-by-line, so "." does not actually match newlines. You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/1739226) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By default python's "re" module has "." match everything except newline. You want to pass re.DOTALL as a flag to your regex.

Example:

```
rx = re.compile('foo\.bar\(.*\)', re.DOTALL)
assert rx.match('foo.bar("mystuff"\n\nand here!)')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.S