# How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?

Tags: string, bash, sed, grep

I am trying to output a string that contains everything between two words of a string:

input:

```
"Here is a String"
```

output:

```
"is a"
```

Using:

```
sed -n '/Here/,/String/p'
```

includes the endpoints, but I don't want to include them.

Comment: What should be the result if the input is `Here is a Here String`?  Or `I Hereby Dub Thee Sir Stringy`?

Comment: FYI. Your command means to print everything between the line that has the word Here and the line that has the word String -- not what you want.

Comment: The other common `sed` FAQ is "how can I extract text between particular lines"; this is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643288/sed-to-extract-text-between-two-strings

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/Here\(.*\)String/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I wanted to find everything between "one is" and "String" in "Here is a one is a String"? (sed -e 's/one is\(.*\)String/\1/' ?

Comment: @user1190650 That would work if you want to see the "Here is a" as well. You can test it out: `echo "Here is a one is a String" | sed -e 's/one is\(.*\)String/\1/'`. If you just want the part between "one is" and "String", then you need to make the regex match the whole line: `sed -e 's/.*one is\(.*\)String.*/\1/'`. In sed, `s/pattern/replacement/` say "substitute 'replacement' for 'pattern'  on each line". It will only change anything that matches "pattern", so if you want it to replace the whole line, you need to make "pattern" match the whole line.

Comment: This breaks when the input is `Here is a String Here is a String`

Comment: Would be great to see the solution for a case : "Here is a blah blah String Here is 1 a blah blah  String Here is 2 a blash blash String" output should pick up only the first substring between Here and String"

Comment: @JayD sed does not support non-greedy matching, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed) for some recommended alternatives.

Comment: @BrianCampbell Thanks Brian for the reference.

Comment: What about if I want also start and end strings?
Like [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/4Kmw09/3). I tried multiple regex, e.g `echo "before text START some text END more text" | sed -n '/START.*?END/g'`

Comment: This answer does not work if there is text before the `Here` and after the `String`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43795984/1902896) for a solution.

Comment: @wheeler A similar case is discussed in the first and second comment on this answer already (the "one is" case), where I discuss what you need to do if your strings are not the exact prefix and suffix of the line.

Comment: This will not work: `echo Here is a String, and Here is b String! | sed -e 's/Here\(.*\)String/\1/'` The answer from @anishsane is better.

Comment: What is the meaning of `\1`?

Answer (score 254):

GNU grep can also support positive & negative look-ahead & look-back:
For your case, the command would be:

```
echo "Here is a string" | grep -o -P '(?<=Here).*(?=string)'
```

If there are multiple occurrences of `Here` and `string`, you can choose whether you want to match from the first `Here` and last `string` or match them individually. In terms of regex, it is called as [greedy match (first case)](https://regex101.com/r/IGG4l8/1/) or [non-greedy match (second case)](https://regex101.com/r/IGG4l8/2/)

```
$ echo 'Here is a string, and Here is another string.' | grep -oP '(?<=Here).*(?=string)' # Greedy match
 is a string, and Here is another 
$ echo 'Here is a string, and Here is another string.' | grep -oP '(?<=Here).*?(?=string)' # Non-greedy match (Notice the '?' after '*' in .*)
 is a 
 is another
```

Comment: Note that GNU grep's `-P` option does not exist in the `grep` included in *BSD, or the ones that come with any SVR4 (Solaris, etc).  In FreeBSD, you can install the `devel/pcre` port which includes `pcregrep`, which supports PCRE (and look-ahead/behind). Older versions of OSX used GNU grep, but in OSX Mavericks, `-P` is derived from FreeBSD's version, which does not include the option.

Comment: Hi, How do I extract distinct content only ?

Comment: This doesn't work because if your ending string "string" occurs more than once, it will get the *last* occurrence, not the *next* occurrence.

Comment: In case of `Here is a string a string`, **both** `" is a "` and `" is a string a "` are valid answers (ignore the quotes), as per the question requirements. It depends on you which one of these **you** want and then answer can be different accordingly. Anyway, for your requirement, this will work: `echo "Here is a string a string" | grep -o -P '(?<=Here).*?(?=string)'`

Comment: Maybe that should be spelled out in the answer properly, though.

Comment: @ghoti `grep -P` flag does not work on MacOS X 10.9 and above. But you can convert it to a `perl` command using the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches

Comment: @Mr-IDE, when I made that comment, 10.9 was the most recent version available. Yes, as I said, the `-P` option does not work because macOS's `grep` comes from FreeBSD. You can get a `pcregrep` binary via the pcre1 package in [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pcre) or [macports](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=pcre).

Comment: This is more way user-friendly that this shitty `sed` - I couldn't get to work `sed`, but `grep` work like a charm for the first time!

Comment: how would you use this on an xml file?

Comment: @kRazzyR, First, you should avoid using text manipulation commands (like awk, sed) for parsing XML. Use `xmlstarlet` instead. It is much easier and works better for XML. Having said that, you can still use sed/awk in the same way for XML as any other text file.

Comment: How to you include `Here` and `string` in the results?

Comment: @Smeterlink, that is much simpler than the original question. `grep -o 'Here.*string'` or  `grep -oP 'Here.*?string'` based on whether you want match to be greedy or non greedy.

Comment: Will this work if the two patterns are on different lines. Tried but not working.

Comment: @BND, you need to enable [multi-line search feature of pcregrep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115). `echo $'Here is \na string' | grep -zoP '(?<=Here)(?s).*(?=string)'`

Comment: @anishsane a sedic solution too `sed -n '/Here/,/string/p'` :). This includes the patterns though.

Comment: @BND, no. That would print the ENTIRE line containing the two words. Try e.g. `echo $'Hello there. Here is \n a string. goodbye there.' | sed ...`

Comment: How to stop at the first occurance?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if the "Here" is present several time and I would like to catch only the text between the last "Here" and "string"?

Comment: @TheLazyFox, I have to check. I don't have an answer off-hand. But a simple hack would be to reverse the input and search string; perform a non-greedy search and reverse the result. (`rev` command does it.)

Comment: @TheLazyFox, you can use sed or perl for this: `perl -nE 'say /.*(?<=Here)(.*)String/'` / `sed -r 's/.*Here(.*)String/\1/'`

Comment: Doesn't work in this case: `echo 00..21 | grep -o -P '(?<=^).*(?=\.)'`. It produces `00.` rather than `00`. How to fix?

Comment: @pmor, this is discussed in the comments earlier and the fix is mentioned in the answer. Use `grep -oP '(?<=^).*?(?=\.)'`

Comment: @anishsane Thanks! I've thought the same. The [lazy](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/why-using-the-greedy-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want) (same as "non-greedy"?) version needs to be used.

Answer (score 98):

The accepted answer does not remove text that could be before `Here` or after `String`. This will:

```
sed -e 's/.*Here\(.*\)String.*/\1/'
```

The main difference is the addition of `.*` immediately before `Here` and after `String`.

Comment: Your answer is promising. One issue though. How can I extract it to the first seen String if there are multiple String in the same line? Thanks

Comment: @MianAsbatAhmad You would want to make the `*` quantifier, between `Here` and `String`, non-greedy (or lazy). However, the type of regex used by sed does not support lazy quantifiers (a `?` immediately after `.*`) according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed) Stackoverflow question. Usually to implement a lazy quantifier you would just match against everything except the token you didn't want to match, but in this case, there isn't just a single token, instead its a whole string, `String`.

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer using awk, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041463/how-to-extract-line-portion-on-the-basis-of-start-substring-and-end-substring-us/51047792#51047792

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the string has line breaks

Comment: It's not supposed to. `.` doesn't match line breaks. If you want to match line breaks, you can replace `.` with something like `[\s\s]`.

Comment: @wheeler replacing . with [\s\s] not removing line breaks .

Comment: Whoops, it is meant to be `[\s\S]`.

Answer (score 47):

You can strip strings in [Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) alone:

```
$ foo="Here is a String"
$ foo=${foo##*Here }
$ echo "$foo"
is a String
$ foo=${foo%% String*}
$ echo "$foo"
is a
$
```

And if you have a GNU grep that includes [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), you can use a zero-width assertion:

```
$ echo "Here is a String" | grep -Po '(?<=(Here )).*(?= String)'
is a
```

Comment: why is this method so slow? when stripping a large html page using this method it takes like 10 seconds.

Comment: @AdamJohns, which method?  The PCRE one?  PCRE is fairly complex to parse, but 10 seconds seems extreme.  If you're concerned, I recommend you [pose a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) including example code, and see what the experts say.

Comment: I think it was so slow for me because it was holding a very large html file's source in a variable. When I wrote contents to file and then parsed the file the speed dramatically increased.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, because it uses pure Bash.

Answer (score 33):

If you have a long file with many multi-line ocurrences, it is useful to first print  number lines:

```
cat -n file | sed -n '/Here/,/String/p'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution which worked in my case (multiple line text file, rather than a single string with no line breaks). Obviously, to have it without line numbering, the `-n` option in `cat` must be omitted.

Comment: ... in which case `cat` can be entirely omitted; `sed` knows how to read a file or standard input.

Answer (score 31):

Through GNU awk,

```
$ echo "Here is a string" | awk -v FS="(Here|string)" '{print $2}'
 is a
```

grep with `-P`(*perl-regexp*) parameter supports `\K`, which helps in discarding the previously matched characters. In our case , the previously matched string was `Here` so it got discarded from the final output.

```
$ echo "Here is a string" | grep -oP 'Here\K.*(?=string)'
 is a 
$ echo "Here is a string" | grep -oP 'Here\K(?:(?!string).)*'
 is a
```

If you want the output to be `is a` then you could try the below,

```
$ echo "Here is a string" | grep -oP 'Here\s*\K.*(?=\s+string)'
is a
$ echo "Here is a string" | grep -oP 'Here\s*\K(?:(?!\s+string).)*'
is a
```

Comment: This does not work for: `echo "Here is a string dfdsf Here is a string" | awk -v FS="(Here|string)" '{print $2}'`, it only returns `is a` instead of should be `is a is a`@Avinash Raj

Answer (score 12):

To understand `sed` command, we have to build it step by step.

Here is your original text

```
user@linux:~$ echo "Here is a String"
Here is a String
user@linux:~$
```

Let's try to remove `Here` string with `s`ubstition option in `sed`

```
user@linux:~$ echo "Here is a String" | sed 's/Here //'
is a String
user@linux:~$
```

At this point, I believe you would be able to remove `String` as well

```
user@linux:~$ echo "Here is a String" | sed 's/String//'
Here is a
user@linux:~$
```

But this is not your desired output.

To combine two sed commands, use `-e` option

```
user@linux:~$ echo "Here is a String" | sed -e 's/Here //' -e 's/String//'
is a
user@linux:~$
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for this - the explanation on what exactly it's doing was very helpful for me to understand

Answer (score 12):

You can use two s commands

```
$ echo "Here is a String" | sed 's/.*Here//; s/String.*//'
 is a
```

Also works

```
$ echo "Here is a StringHere is a String" | sed 's/.*Here//; s/String.*//'
 is a

$ echo "Here is a StringHere is a StringHere is a StringHere is a String" | sed 's/.*Here//; s/String.*//'
 is a
```

Answer (score 9):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Here/!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/String/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D' file
```

This presents each representation of text between two markers (in this instance `Here` and `String`) on a newline and preserves newlines within the text.

Answer (score 8):

All the above solutions have deficiencies where the last search string is repeated elsewhere in the string.  I found it best to write a bash function.

```
    function str_str {
      local str
      str="${1#*${2}}"
      str="${str%%$3*}"
      echo -n "$str"
    }

    # test it ...
    mystr="this is a string"
    str_str "$mystr" "this " " string"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\1` (refer to http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4):

```
echo "Hello is a String" | sed 's/Hello\(.*\)String/\1/g'
```

The contents that is inside the brackets will be stored as `\1`.

Comment: This removes strings instead of output something in between. Try removing "Hello" with "is" in the sed command and it will output "Hello  a"

Answer (score 1):

**Problem.**  My stored Claws Mail messages are wrapped as follows, and I am trying to extract the Subject lines:

```
Subject: [SLC38A9 lysosomal arginine sensor; mTORC1 pathway] Key molecular
 link in major cell growth pathway: Findings point to new potential
 therapeutic target in pancreatic cancer [mTORC1 Activator SLC38A9 Is
 Required to Efflux Essential Amino Acids from Lysosomes and Use Protein as
 a Nutrient] [Re: Nutrient sensor in key growth-regulating metabolic pathway
 identified [Lysosomal amino acid transporter SLC38A9 signals arginine
 sufficiency to mTORC1]]
Message-ID: <20171019190902.18741771@VictoriasJourney.com>
```

Per A2 in this thread, [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words) the first expression, below, "works" as long as the matched text does not contain a newline:

```
grep -o -P '(?<=Subject: ).*(?=molecular)' corpus/01

[SLC38A9 lysosomal arginine sensor; mTORC1 pathway] Key
```

However, despite trying numerous variants (`.+?; /s; ...`), I could not get these to work:

```
grep -o -P '(?<=Subject: ).*(?=link)' corpus/01
grep -o -P '(?<=Subject: ).*(?=therapeutic)' corpus/01
etc.
```

**Solution 1.**

Per [Extract text between two strings on different lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015153/extract-text-between-two-strings-on-different-lines)

```
sed -n '/Subject: /{:a;N;/Message-ID:/!ba; s/\n/ /g; s/\s\s*/ /g; s/.*Subject: \|Message-ID:.*//g;p}' corpus/01
```

which gives

```
[SLC38A9 lysosomal arginine sensor; mTORC1 pathway] Key molecular link in major cell growth pathway: Findings point to new potential therapeutic target in pancreatic cancer [mTORC1 Activator SLC38A9 Is Required to Efflux Essential Amino Acids from Lysosomes and Use Protein as a Nutrient] [Re: Nutrient sensor in key growth-regulating metabolic pathway identified [Lysosomal amino acid transporter SLC38A9 signals arginine sufficiency to mTORC1]]
```

**Solution 2.***

Per [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed?rq=1)

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' corpus/01
```

will replace newlines with a space.

Chaining that with A2 in [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words), we get:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' corpus/01 | grep -o -P '(?<=Subject: ).*(?=Message-ID:)'
```

which gives

```
[SLC38A9 lysosomal arginine sensor; mTORC1 pathway] Key molecular  link in major cell growth pathway: Findings point to new potential  therapeutic target in pancreatic cancer [mTORC1 Activator SLC38A9 Is  Required to Efflux Essential Amino Acids from Lysosomes and Use Protein as  a Nutrient] [Re: Nutrient sensor in key growth-regulating metabolic pathway  identified [Lysosomal amino acid transporter SLC38A9 signals arginine  sufficiency to mTORC1]]
```

This variant removes double spaces:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g; s/\s\s*/ /g' corpus/01 | grep -o -P '(?<=Subject: ).*(?=Message-ID:)'
```

giving

```
[SLC38A9 lysosomal arginine sensor; mTORC1 pathway] Key molecular link in major cell growth pathway: Findings point to new potential therapeutic target in pancreatic cancer [mTORC1 Activator SLC38A9 Is Required to Efflux Essential Amino Acids from Lysosomes and Use Protein as a Nutrient] [Re: Nutrient sensor in key growth-regulating metabolic pathway identified [Lysosomal amino acid transporter SLC38A9 signals arginine sufficiency to mTORC1]]
```

Comment: nice adventure :))

Answer (score 1):

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Here is the example using [`rg`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```
$ echo Here is a String | rg 'Here\s(.*)\sString' -r '$1'
is a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my not-so-elegant but working solution:

```
$ echo 'Here is a String' | sed 's/Here/\n/g'| sed 's/String/\n/g'| sed -r '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'

is a
```

but works with `Here is a String Here is a second String` also:

```
$ echo 'Here is a String Here is a second String' | sed 's/Here/\n/g'| sed 's/String/\n/g'| sed -r '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'

is a
is a second
```

or:

```
$ echo 'Here is a String Here is a second String Here is last String' | sed 's/Here/\n/g'| sed 's/String/\n/g'| sed -r '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'

is a
is a second
is last
```