# Extract string located after or between matched pattern(s)

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Given a string "pos:665181533 pts:11360 t:11.360000 crop=720:568:0:4 some more words"

Is it possible to extract string between "crop=" and the following space using bash and grep?

So if I match "crop=" how can I extract anything after it and before the following white space?

Basically, I need "720:568:0:4" to be printed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
grep -o -E 'crop=[^ ]+' | sed 's/crop=//'
```

It uses `sed` which is also a standard command. You can, of course, replace it with another sequence of greps, but only if it's really needed.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit the  [^ ]+ part?

Answer (score 3):

I would use `sed` as follows:

```
echo "pos:665181533 pts:11360 t:11.360000 crop=720:568:0:4 some more words" | sed 's/.*crop=\([0-9.:]*\)\(.*\)/\1/'
```

Explanation:

```
s/          : substitute
.*crop=     : everything up to and including "crop="
\([0-9.:]\) : match only numbers and '.' and ':' - I call this the backslash-bracketed expression
\(.*\)      : match 'everything else' (probably not needed)
/\1/        : and replace with the first backslash-bracketed expression you found
```

Comment: This is a bit excessive... it "eats" every part of the expression - but it does spell out how to make a regex work for you in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work (need to recheck my reference):

```
awk '/crop=([0-9:]*?)/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another way with bash pattern substitution

```
PAT="pos:665181533 pts:11360 t:11.360000 crop=720:568:0:4 some more words"
RES=${PAT#*crop=}
echo ${RES%% *}
```

- first remove all up to and including `crop=` found from left to right (#)
- then remove all from and including the first space found from right to left (%%)