# bash sed/grep extract text between 2 words

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

My problem is the same as it's here, except I only want the first occurrence, ignore all the rest:

[How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/bash-sed-grep-text-between-two-words)

In his example if it would be:

```
 input: "Here is a String Here is a String"
```

But I only care about the first "is"

```
echo "Here is a String Here is a String" | grep -Po '(?<=(Here )).*(?= String)'
```

output: "is a String Here is a"

Is this even possible with grep? I could use sed as well for the job.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to find lines containing a pattern, use `grep` -- or `egrep`. If you want to find lines containing a pattern and then transform it in some way before printing the result, use `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp happens to be matching against the longest string that sits between "Here" and "String". That is, indeed, "*Here **is a String Here is a** String*". This is the default behaviour of the `*` quantifier.

```
$ echo "Here is a String Here is a String" | grep -Po '(?<=(Here )).*(?= String)'
is a String Here is a
```

If you want to match the shortest, you may put a `?` (greediness modifier) just after the `*` quantifier:

```
$ echo "Here is a String Here is a String" | grep -Po '(?<=(Here )).*?(?= String)'
is a
is a
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first word you can use `grep -o '^[^ ]*'`:

```
echo "Here is a String Here is a String" | grep -Po '(?<=(Here )).*(?= String)' | grep -o '^[^ ]*'
```

And you can pipe grep to grep multiple times to compose simple commands into complex ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/ String.*//;s/.*Here //'
```