# Get GitHub repo names

Tags: git, bash, github

Using `curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos` gives a lot of extra output.  How do you use the GitHub api to output all repo names, for example:

- Repo1
- Repo2
- Repo3

Comment: Show us what you've tried? GitHub has pretty extensive documentation for their APIs, and I suspect you can find many examples via your favorite search engine or even here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried a lot of things, but didn't want to complicate the question (it seems like I included everything in the "specific reason" above: desired behavior, specific problem, and shortest code, so I'm not sure what the problem is).  Since you asked, here they are:

1. $ curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos |
test.txt grep -o -p '.*name="\K.*?(?=".*)' test.txt

2. $ curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos |
grep -Po 'name="\K.*?(?=")'

3. curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/orgs/repos |
grep '"name":'

Comment: use `jq`... e.g., `curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos | jq '.[].name'`. Get `jq` [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track - you have selected the right API (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories).

Since the response is JSON, you would ideally use a JSON tool to filter the content, but you can start with a simple grep like this:

```
curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos | grep "full_name"
```

This will print all of the repo names. You can extend that solution with more elaborate logic if you like.

Related:

- [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121718/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting-in-linux

Comment: Thanks for the starter!  This was simpler than I thought.  Using curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/orgs/repos |
grep '"name":' still gives a lot of extra content:  '% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
"name": "OctopusDeploy-PowerShell-Modules",
  "name": "GuardRail-PowerShell-Modules",
  "name": "Infrastructure-PowerShell-Modules",1
  "name": "Deployment-PowerShell-Modules",0'

How do I extract the name only?

Comment: From this post [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words, I tried:

'$ curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos |
grep '"name":"\K.*?(?=")'

But it doesn't output anything.  I thought it might be because there is a space after the : that is not being interpreted, but I tried back-ticking it with no luck:

'$ curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos |
grep '"name":` "\K.*?(?=")'

Comment: use `jq`... e.g., `curl --user "UserName" https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos | jq '.[].name'`. Get `jq` [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)