# Grep for Multiple instances of string between a substring and a character?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, pcre

Can you please tell me how to Grep for every instance of a substring that occurs multiple times on multiple lines within a file?

I've looked at 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131399/extract-value-between-two-search-patterns-on-same-line
and [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

But my problem is slightly different - each substring will be immediately preceded by the string: `name">` and will be terminated be a `<` character immediately after the last character of the substring I want.

So one line might be

```
<"name">Bob<125><adje></name><"name">Dave<123><adfe></name><"name">Fred<125><adfe></name>
```

And I would like the output to be:

```
Bob
Dave
Fred
```

Comment: Showing just one sample line is extremely unlikely to help us figure out a robust solution for you. Your text says the issue is related to multiple lines so show multiple lines. Also use the `{}` editor button to format your input/output/code files.

Comment: so you're really trying to parse XML with a reg-exp? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 for why not ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the relies so far, sorry for my poor question formatting!

Comment: Thanks for the relies so far, sorry for my poor question formatting!

I realised that what I really would have preferred is if the multiple sets of data were no on the same line, so I did this (got the idea reading SO):
`code`
grep name\"\> | awk '{ gsub("\"name\">", "\n\"name\">") } 1' 
`code`
to insert a new line in front of every "name" field, (and others) I then used a combination of Grep and Cut to hack out just the data, it's slow and inelegant, but it does work.

I will of course look at the other answers and compare them, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although `awk` is not the best tool for xml processing, it will help if your xml structure and data simple enough.

```
$ awk -F"[<>]" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i=="\"name\"") print $(++i)}' file
Bob
Dave
Fred
```

I doubt that the tag is `<"name">` though. If it's `<name>`, without the quotes change the condition in the script to `$i=="name"`

Answer (score 0):

gawk

```
awk -vRS='<"name">|<' '/^[A-Z]/' file
Bob
Dave
Fred
```