# How to use sed to extract text between two bar signs (i.e. '|')?

Tags: unix, sed

I would like to extract text that falls between two `|` signs in a file with multiple lines. For instance, I want to extract `P16` from `sp|P16|SM2`. I have found a possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words). However, I cannot apply the answer to my case. I am using the following:

```
sed -n '/|/,/|/ p' filename
```

or this by escaping the `|` sign:

```
sed -n '/\|/,/\|/ p' filename
```

But what I receive as result are all the lines in the file unchanged even though I am using `-n` to suppress automatic printing of pattern space. Any ideas what I am missing?

**[EDIT]**:

I can get the desired result using the following. However, I would like an explanation why the above mentioned is not working:

```
sed 's/^sp|//' filename | sed 's/|.*//'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

Comment: @BenjaminW. You can see that I have had included the exact link in my question saying that the answer is there already...

Comment: Yes, but the way you tried it was using the wrong approach of the question itself rather than the correct top answer.

Comment: @ I see! Well, I was not able to use the top answer to solve my problem. Do you suggest that I should delete this question?

Comment: No no, I'm not suggesting you should delete it. Arguably, the questions aren't exactly the same as the other question has the delimiters at the beginning and end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is better choice for column based data:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $2}'
```

will give you `P16`

#### sed one-liner:

The following sed one-liner will only leave the 2nd column for you:

```
kent$  echo "sp|P16|SM2"|sed 's/[^|]*|//;s/|[^|]*//' 
P16
```

Or using grouping:

```
kent$  echo "sp|P16|SM2"|sed 's/.*|\([^|]*\)|.*/\1/'     
P16
```

#### Short explanation why your two commands didn't work:

```
1) sed -n '/|/,/|/ p' filename
```

This sed will print lines between two **lines** which containing `|`

```
2) sed -n '/\|/,/\|/ p' filename
```

Sed takes BRE as default. If you escape the `|`, you gave them special meaning, the logical OR. again, the `/pat1/,/pat2/` address was wrong usage for your case, it checks lines, not within a line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I am really interested to get it into working with `sed`.

Comment: I see! It makes sense now! Thanks for the elaboration! :)

Answer (score 2):

the tool for this task is `cut`

```
$ echo "sp|P16|SM2" | cut -d'|' -f2
P16
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. However, I was interested to know how to do it with `sed`.