# Get specific Text between Specific Tags

Tags: regex, awk, sed

At the top of my HTML files, I have...

```
<H2>City</H2>
<P>Liverpool</P>
```

or

```
<H2>City</H2>
<P>Dublin</P>
```

I want to output the text between the

tags straight after `<H2>City</H2>` instances.  So in the examples above which are separate files, I want to print out Liverpool and in the second example, Dublin.

Looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words), I try:

```
sed -e 's/City\(.*\)\/P/\1/'
```

which I hope would get me half way there... but that just prints out the entire file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `sed -e 's/<H2>City<\/H2>\s*<P>\(.*\)<\/P>/\1/'`?

Comment: @horcrux, I try that on mac, passing the file name for the file and it still outputs the entire file.

Comment: You really shouldn't use regex as a parsing tool

Comment: You can't parse [X]HTML with regex ..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: @Cyrus that's a better way to go thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Cyrus xmllint won't work well unless the html document is well formed.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!  You need multi-char RS support though (gawk has it)

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' -v RS='<H2>City</H2>' 'NF{print $3}' file
```

another approach can be

```
$ awk 'c&&c--{sub(/<[^>]*>/,""); print} /<H2>City<\/H2>/{c=1}' file
```

find the next record after City and trim the angle brackets...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?s)(?<=City<\/H2>\n<P>).*?(?=<\/P>)
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Q9XrHR/1)**

**sed**

```
sed -e 's/(?s)(?<=City<\/H2>\n<P>).*?(?=<\/P>)/'
```

Comment: I am on mac and this are just files that want to just return Dublin, Liverpool from. So how do I do that with your regex?

Comment: Using lookbehind when not needed is an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I checked and the `\s` seem not work for spaces. You should use the newline character `\n`:

```
sed -e 's/<H2>City<\/H2>\n<P>\(.*\)<\/P>/\1/'
```

There is **no need** of use lookbehind (like above), that is an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

With sed, you can use the `n` command to read next line after your pattern. Then just remove the tag to output your content:

```
sed -n '/<H2>City<\/H2>/n;s/ *<\/*P> *//gp;' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work in your mac:

```
echo -e "<H2>City</H2>\n<P>Dublin</P>" |awk -F"[<>]" '/City/{getline;print $3}'
Dublin
```