# Using SED to find a word between 2 back slashes

Tags: sed

It is maybe a noob question but i cannot find an answer.
How can i use SED to find Santa83_4. The name Santa83_4 is an example and can be anything with any charcater.

....\randomtext\randomtext\name\Santa83_4\rate\randomtext\randomtext...

Thanks is advance

Comment: this appears to have been covered in another topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words

Comment: I know that topic, and played with it. It did not give me the answer i need.

Comment: Why? I mean why bother trying to find "foo" using "sed" on a string so you can print "foo" when you could just do `echo "foo"` if all you want is a tool that outputs "foo". What are you REALLY trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***grep*** approach:

```
s='...\randomtext\randomtext\name\Santa83_4\rate\randomtext\randomtext..'
echo $s | grep -Po '\\name\\\K[^\\]+'
```

---

***sed*** approach:

```
echo $s | sed -n 's/.*\\name\\\([^\\]*\).*/\1/p'
```

---

The output(for both approaches):

```
Santa83_4
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much