# Extract text between 2 markers

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

**input**:

```
random adsf 845 asdsf.$Ecdda-string0.rand me39 84abd    
dee rand a[s% 845 a1sEdsf.$cdNda-string1.rand me39 84abd
```

**output** - keep everything between `da-` and `.`

```
string0    
string1
```

**what I have tried so far**:

```
sed -e 's/.*da-\(.*\)./\1/' file 
grep -o -P '(?<=da-).*(?=.)' file
grep -o -P '(?<=da-).*(?=\.)' file
```

Comment: `grep -o -P '(?<=da-).*(?=\.)' file` works for me on GNU grep with PCRE available... in what way it fails for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43795984/1135424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sed was close. Needed to be `\..*` at the end of your matching

```
$ cat test.txt
random adsf 845 asdsf.$Ecdda-string0.rand me39 84abd
dee rand a[s% 845 a1sEdsf.$cdNda-string1.rand me39 84abd

$ sed 's#.*da-\([^.]*\)\..*#\1#g' test.txt
string0
string1
```

Answer (score 0):

with `grep` look behind..

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=da-)[^.]+' file

string0
string1
```

Comment: it works fine; thanx a lot but zzevannn was faster; sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[-.]' '{print $3}' file

string0
string1
```

Useing provided FS print third field.

Comment: You should provide some explanation