# How to select lines between two same marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/perl or any other command line tool

Tags: shell, perl, awk, sed, pattern-matching

Using `awk` or `perl` or any command line tool, how can I select lines which are occurring between two same marker patterns? There may be multiple sections marked with these patterns. So, the block starts at first occurrence of the pattern and ends at the second occurrence of the pattern. Everything ignored after that till the next occurrence of the pattern which is considered first occurrence and repeat.

For example: Suppose the file contains:

```
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
abc
1
2
3
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
abc
4
5
6
abc
stu
abc
```

And the pattern is abc. So, I need the output as:

```
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
abc
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
abc
abc
stu
abc
```

I tried various solutions from the other related questions, but they were all for different start and end patterns.

[How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or)

[Extract lines between two patterns from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177721/extract-lines-between-two-patterns-from-a-file)

[Extract text between 2 markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386658/extract-text-between-2-markers)
[Extract lines between 2 tokens in a text file using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857424/extract-lines-between-2-tokens-in-a-text-file-using-bash)

I updated the solutions as per my need, which looked something like this:

```
perl -lne 'if(/abc/){$flag=1; print} elsif(/abc/){$flag=0}' file.txt
awk '/abc/,/abc/' file.txt
```

I only ended up getting lines which contain the pattern and not the text block between them.

How can I do this in `awk` or `perl` or any command line tool, such that I get the text block with same patterns ?

Comment: As this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some
attempt first. Don't post it as a comment, an image, a table or a link
to an off-site service but use text and include it to your original
question. Thanks.

Comment: `sed -n '/abc/,/abc/p' file.txt`

Comment: or even `sed -n '/abc/,//p' file`

Comment: `perl -ne 'print if /abc/.../abc/' test3.txt`

Comment: Thanks for editing and fixing the question :)

Comment: @potong your solution worked. It looks pretty simple as well. Can you add here about how that command is evaluated ?

Comment: It is the same as @Shawn's. The empty regexp just repeats the previous regexp.

Comment: You should have included sample input/output where there was an odd number of occurrences of the marker and cases where it appeared in other contexts (other parts of the line, or as substrings). Otherwise you're likely to get solutions that only work for perfect, sunny day cases and then fail later on your real data.

Comment: A comment for the Perl code you show: you want to flip the flag -- set it if not set and unset it if set, on lines with `/abc/`; and then, print if flag is set.  Also, need to print on a line when flag is _unset_ (which won't happen with the previous logic alone so we need to add that).  So  `perl -wnE'if (/abc/) { if ($f) { $f= 0; print } else { $f = 1 } }  print if $f'`.  Now this works.   And this is what one of solutions in my post does, just more concisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is with the [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators), the three-dot variant

```
perl -wne'/abc/ ... /abc/ and print' data.txt
```

---

Another way, with an explicit flag and all but more concise

```
perl -wnlE' /abc/ and $f ^= 1; $f and say' data.txt
```

This doesn't print the end marker though.  To have both start and end markers printed

```
perl -wnlE' ($f or /abc/) and say; /abc/ and $f ^= 1' data.txt
```

Explanation --

In Perl all [logical operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Logical-Not) short-circuit. Consider `A and B`: if the first expression (`A`) evaluates to something "falsey" then `B` is *not evaluated* -- that code doesn't run.  Thus `A and B` is mostly equivalent to `if (A) { B }`.

I use the short-circuiting nature here to streamline code for a one-liner; it's normally far clearer in normal code to write it out nicely. So, the first statement amounts to

- `if ($f or /abc/) { say }` -- print the line if `$f` evaluates to "truthy" (flag is set) or we are on the line with `abc`.  The second condition is matched by regex, `$_ =~ m/abc/`, where `m` may be omitted with `//` delimiters and the pattern [binds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators) to `$_` by default so that can be omitted as well -- thus just `/abc/`, which returns true/false.

  Now for setting that flag...
- Next statement, we test `/abc/` and if-it-matches-then (per the short-circuiting `and`) we do `$f ^= 1`.  This second expression uses bitwise `^`, as follows.

  When two numbers are [bitwise XOR-ed](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Bitwise-Or-and-Exclusive-Or) each pair of their bits is XOR-ed -- the resulting bit is set if *one of them is set but not the other*, and it's not set otherwise.  So `0101 ^ 1100` gives `1001` (higher four bits omitted here; needed for testing)

  Then doing it with `1` results in flipping the lowest bit: `6 ^ 1` produces 7 (`0110 ^ 1` --> `0111`) while `7 ^ 1` returns `6`.  And we flip between `0` and `1`. Then we assign that back, `$f = $f ^ 1;` for which there is syntax `$f ^= 1`.

  Thus this sets the flag if it is unset (`0`-->`1`) and the other way round, on a line with `abc`, as needed for the next line.

---

Of course since this reads from a file and line endings aren't touched one can use `print` instead of `say` and then only `-wne` switches are needed.

I just liked `say` better here. Also, `-lE` with `say` handles a case where this filter is fed strings wihtout linefeeds, as well.

Comment: Please show what you have seen/done and then we can discuss

Comment: If you use `-l` you can just use `print`, no need for `-E` and `say`. Though of course, you would not need to handle line endings at all, since you are not changing them.

Comment: @zdim I tried your solution, but I see one missing thing with your code. it is missing the start marker for the next block. So the output is looking like this:
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
abc
stu

It is slightly off from my desired output

Comment: @RamanjaneyuluGudipati  Indeed. (The end marker isn't printed.) Added a version that prints both

Comment: @TLP Well yes; I just _wanted_  `say`, for aesthetics (it's ok to laugh :).  While, on the other hand, once can also imagine lines being sent to this filter without line endings.  Having `-lE` and `say` covers both uses.  Added a note

Comment: @zdim thanks for the solution. Can you please help me walkthrough the code ?

Comment: You can use the `...` operator here: `perl -ne'/abc/ ... /abc/ and print' data.txt`

Comment: @RamanjaneyuluGudipati Added explanation.  It's probably messy right now, will edit later.  Let me know what/if is unclear

Comment: @TLP  "_ou can use the ... operator_"  -- yeah, I was drawn to what I posted originally, expecting that someone would post w/ range operator.  If you don't want to then I'll leave it in this post as well...

Comment: @RamanjaneyuluGudipati Btw, added another (simpler) solution to the top

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content

```
be
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
abc
1
2
3
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
abc
4
5
6
abc
stu
abc
```

then

```
awk '$0=="abc"{cnt+=1;print;next}cnt%2' file.txt
```

gives output

```
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
abc
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
abc
abc
stu
abc
```

Explanation: If whole line (`$0`) is `abc` then increase `cnt` by one, output it and go forth to `next` line. For all others lines output it if and only if `cnt` is odd (remainder of division by 2 is non-zero). **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that marker always spans whole line, if this does not hold true ignore this answer entirely.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/^abc$/{ if (++c%2) { rec="" } else { print rec $0; next } } {rec=rec $0 ORS}' file
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
abc
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
abc
abc
stu
abc
```

You need to store the record between the 2 delimiters like that otherwise if you had an odd number of "abc"s it'd print the text after the last "abc" even though it wasn't between 2 "abc"s as required, e.g. given this input:

```
$ cat file1
abc
good
abc
abc
bad
```

this only prints the text between the one pair of "abc"s:

```
$ awk '/^abc$/{ if (++c%2) { rec="" } else { print rec $0; next } } {rec=rec $0 ORS}' file1
abc
good
abc
```

but try any of the other existing answers with that input:

```
$ perl -wnlE' ($f or /abc/) and say; /abc/ and $f ^= 1' file1
abc
good
abc
abc
bad
```

```
$ awk '$0=="abc"{cnt+=1;print;next}cnt%2' file1
abc
good
abc
abc
bad
```

```
$ awk '/abc/&&!((f=!f)&&f);f' file1
abc
good
abc
abc
bad
```

I expect you'd have problems with some of them if `abc` appeared in other contexts too, e.g. `fooabcbar` in between 2 `abc` lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$0="abc"&&(!(f=!f))&&!f;f' file
```

which is about the same as:

```
$ awk '
$0="abc" {
    if(!(f=!f))
        print
}
{
    if(f)
        print
}' file
```

Output:

```
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
abc
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
abc
abc
stu
abc
```

Using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) it can be simplified to:

```
$ awk '$0="abc" &&!((f=!f)&&f);f' file
```

If your data has Windows line-endings (\r\n) you need to set `-v RS="\r\n"` (or `RS="\r?\n"`).