# Keep string between start and end pattern

Tags: regex, string, unix

I have a text file containing this kind of content :

```
d__Affenpinscher|c__Abyssinian|h__Kathiawari|
a__Gold|y__Slix|c__Kathiawari|c__Cact
```

And I would like to obtain all the occurence that start with "c__" and end with "|" so that the final result is :

```
c__Abyssinian
c__Cact
```

I'm not that good with regular expression, so thanks for your help in advance.

edit : I'm looking for a bash command so grep/sed/awk are available
I tried to start from a basic example like :

```
sed -n "/<PRE>/,/<\/PRE>/p" input.html
```

with < PRE > and < /PRE > beeing the start and the end of the pattern
to

```
sed -n "/c__/,/|/p" breedList.txt > breedC.txt
```

But I didn't obtained the wanted output

Edit 2 : I tried to adapt this answer from a similar thread [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13245961) but I must be doing something wrong since my output is juste empty.

Here is the command I tried :

```
echo "d__Affenpinscher|c__Abyssinian|h__Kathiawari|" | grep -o -P '(?<=c__).*?(?=|)'
```

Comment: What is the context of your problem?  Are you using a particular programming language?  Do you just want to manipulate text files in Bash?

Comment: The `addr1,addr2` syntax in `sed` selects *lines* between the line selected by `addr1` and the line selected by `addr2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from  [rkta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8699120/rkta) did the trick, thanks :) :

```
echo "d__Affenpinscher|c__Abyssinian|h__Kathiawari|" | grep -o -P '(?<=c__).*?(?=\|)' The vertical bar | is a special character and needs to be escaped.

You say: start with "c__" and end with "|", but c__Cact doesn't end with |
```