# Regex: Extract string between string1 and string2, whereas string2 can be one of many strings

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, extract

I got multiple text files that resemble dictionary entries. One such text file can look like this:

```
MEANING:
content1
content2
IDIOM:
content3
content4
```

Another can be like this:

```
MEANING:
content1
content2
SYNONYMS:
content2
content3
content5
```

Now my wish is to extract the content of "MEANING" section using one sed command line.
Here is my idea for the first text file, where "IDIOM" comes after the "MEANING" part:

```
cat dicentry1.txt | sed -e 's/MEANING\(.*\)IDIOM/\1/')
```

Thing is, that the output is:

```
MEANING:
content1
content2
IDIOM:
content3
```

However, this doesn't even work yet, even though user "Brian Campbell" suggested exact same line with just other values in this thread: [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

My second problem would be to do this with the second file, where "SYNONYMS" comes after the "MEANING" part. Technically, I could do just the same as above but with "/SYNONYMS" instead of "/IDIOM". However, wouldn't be something like this possible?

**DISCLAIMER: It is in idea and the syntax may be completely wrong, I apologize for that in advance T.T**

```
cat anydicentry.txt | sed -e 's/MEANING\(.*\)\(IDIOM|SYNONYM\)/\1/')
```

What this line is suppose to do is to copy everything after "MEANING" to the point where either "IDIOM" or "SYNONYMS" appears. However, I still can't get this working and I have no idea how I could implement it.

I hope that you understand my two issues I am having.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: `sed -e 's/MEANING\(.*\)IDIOM/\1/'` would work if you had `MEANING some text here IDIOM` on one line. `sed` only searches on a single line by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^MEANING:$/,/^[A-Z]*:$/{/^MEANING:$/d;/^[A-Z]*:$/d;p}' file
```

Output:

```
content1
content2
```

Answer (score 2):

For processing files line by line like this `awk` is much better tool as `awk` is complete programming language.

```
awk '/^(IDIOM|SYNONYMS)/{p=0} p; /^MEANING/{p=1}' file
```

```
content1
content2
```

Note that **same output** is retrieved with both of your input files.

**Explanation:**

- `/^(IDIOM|SYNONYMS)/{p=0}`: When line starts with `IDIOM` or `SYNONYMS` then reset a flag `p=0`
- `p;`: When `p==1` then print each line (default action)
- `/^MEANING/{p=1}`: When line starts with `MEANING` then set a flag `p=1`

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks alot for your answer!

Isn't there a way to use sed instead of awk?

Comment: It can be done using `sed` as you can see in answer posted by Cyrus. Though as you can see it is much more straight forward using `awk`.