# how to extract line portion on the basis of start substring and end substring using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a multiline file with text having no spaces.

```
Thereisacat;whichisverycute.Thereisadog;whichisverycute.
Thereisacat;whichisverycute.Thereisadog;whichisverycute.
```

I want to extract string between cat and cute (first occurrence not second) that is  the output is

```
;whichisvery
;whichisvery
```

I am close to getting it but I end up getting string from cat to the last cute with the command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words/43795984?noredirect=1#comment89094299_43795984).

```
sed -e 's/.*cat\(.*\)cute.*/\1/'
```

I am getting

```
;whichisverycute.Thereisadog;whichisvery
;whichisverycute.Thereisadog;whichisvery
```

How can I get the text from cat to the first occurrence of cute not last?

Comment: Are perl solutions OK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the input you posted all you need is:

```
$ awk -F'cat|cute' '{print $2}' file
;whichisvery
;whichisvery
```

Comment: This one works better on my real file. For some reason the first answer is doing great on above example but not working on my real file. I think this answer is handling the complex string in a better way. Please try similar answer in sed too and thanks for the answer.

Comment: What does `Please try similar answer in sed` mean? There is no similar sed answer.

Comment: hmm okay cool. I thought this problem could be solved in many ways.

Comment: The problem can be solved in many ways, as you can see in the various answers you got, but it can't be solved the same way in all tools as different tools have different functionalities.

Answer (score 4):

In `sed`:

```
sed 's/cute.*//;s/.*cat//' Input_file
```

In `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/cute.*/,"");sub(/^.*cat/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

Comment: I didnt down vote your answer. I will up vote it because both are spot on.