# More elegant way to extract substring in shell

Tags: regex, bash

I wrote regex to get chartname(auth-token-service)). But this seems very crude, can someone write a more precise way.

```sh
chartname=`echo my-auth-token-service=xxx.azurecr.io/auth-token-service:latest | cut -d= -f1 | sed -e "s/^.*-//"`
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to extract here?

Comment: i want to get chartname should print auth-token-service

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong with this approach.

Comment: I don't feel it's much better, but you can try `sed "s/.*\/\(.*\):.*/\1/"` if you just want sed

Comment: I want very clean, Like the use of sed not like cut and then sed. The reason this is not much readable.I am running in loop and want to get chartname ,reponame and tagName.

$i value is "lsr-auth-token-service=xxx.azurecr.io/auth-token-service:latest"
chartNmae= auth-token-service
reponame=xxx.azurecr.io
tagname=latest

chartName=`echo $i | cut -d= -f1 | sed -e "s/^.*-//"`
    repoName=`echo $i | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d/ -f2 | cut -d: -f1`
    tagName=`echo $i | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d/ -f2 | cut -d: -f2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words

Answer (score 2):

> Gets text between '=' and '/'

`sed "s/.*=\(.*\)\/.*/\1/"` = xxx.azurecr.io

> Gets text between '/' and ':'

`sed "s/.*\/\(.*\):.*/\1/"` = auth-token-service

> Gets text after ':'

`sed "s/.*:\(.*\)/\1/"` = latest

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the format of token, but if I understood correctly you just want the part after the slash and before the colon.

```sh
echo my-auth-token-service=xxx.azurecr.io/auth-token-service:latest | sed -e 's/^.\+\/\([^\/]\+\):[^:]\+$/\1/'
```

Comment: i want to extract chartname ,and value should return by regex "auth-token-service"

Comment: @Kelvin that much better. Can you help me to get reponame and tag.Repo name should return "xxx.azurecr.io" and tag should return "latest"

Answer (score 0):

The Unix shell has parameter expansion built in. You can't nest these, so it takes multiple steps, but you avoid the overhead of starting multiple external processes.

```sh
var='my-auth-token-service=xxx.azurecr.io/auth-token-service:latest'
chartname=${var%%=*}
chartname=${chartname#*-}
```

The suffix operator `${var%pattern}` returns the value of `$var` with any suffix matching `pattern` removed; the `${var#pattern}` operator does the same for a prefix match. Doubling the operator changes it to trim the longest possible pattern match instead of the shortest. (These are shell glob patterns, not regular expressions, though.)

If you require a one-liner, you can refactor the `cut` into the `sed` script.

```
chartname=$(sed 's/[^-]*\([^=]*\)=.*/\1/' <<< 'my-auth-token-service=xxx.azurecr.io/auth-token-service:latest')
```

Notice the modernized syntax `$(cmd ...)` over the obsolescent `` `cmd ...` `` and the Bash "here string" with `<<<` (not POSIX-compatible though).

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a regex solution:

```
string=my-auth-token-service=xxx.azurecr.io/auth-token-service:latest
[[ $string =~ /([^:]*) ]] && chartname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

This assumes that the chartname is always between the `/` and the `:`. Note that `chartname` would be unassigned with this, if the reges does not match.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` only tested on the GNU variant.

```sh
var=my-auth-token-service=xxx.azurecr.io/auth-token-service:latest

echo "$var" | awk -F'[=:/]' -vOFS='\n' '{print $1, $2, $3, $NF}'
```

Output

```
my-auth-token-service
xxx.azurecr.io
auth-token-service
latest
```

Comment: This extracts the image name, not the string before the equals sign. (I had a hard time understanding exactly which part the OP is trying to extract, too.)

Comment: @tripleee, I have updated the answer, since I'm not sure either what the output is, I have every field :-).