# Bash - get String between two characters

Tags: linux, bash

how can i get the string between two specific characters, only in bash [with out using grep or sed]

e.g

```
input=hostname~web:sit
```

I want to extract `web` from the above input

`${hostname#*~}` gives me output as `web:sit`, but i need only `web` in the output

From the other post i can see

`% strips from end of $var,` up to pattern. But not sure how to apply it.

Any help please

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/.*~([^:]+):.*/\1/' <<< "$input"`

Comment: `awk -F '[~:]' '{print $2}' <<< "$input"`

Comment: @0stone0: That doesn't seem right dupe because that is `grep` specific question and here OP wants to do this in `bash` itself.

Comment: There's a bash only solution just below your answer. Not using the extglob, however the question still remains the same?

Comment: No questions cannot be same as other question is specifically asking **using grep**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately that is also not correct dupe because that is asking how to do that in `sed/grep`. Please understand `bash` is different language and `grep/sed/awk` are different.

Comment: Yea, I understand there's a difference between sed, grep and bash. Kinda contradict to give an sed answer on this bash question anyway.

Comment: If I wanted to post just `sed` based answer I could have posted about an hour ago. That is the reason I just left that as comment only. I posted an answer only when I got a bash only solution working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `extglob` in `bash`, you can do this in **single step**:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
input='hostname~web:sit'
echo "${input//@(*~|:*)/}"

web
```

Here `@(*~|:*)` matches a substring from start to `~` character OR a substring from `:` to end. Using `//` we replace all such instances with an empty string.

---

There is a `sed` solution as well:

```sh
sed -E 's/.*~([^:]+):.*/\1/' <<< "$input"

web
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when i try the commands the echo is printing the input back instead of `web`                  -bash-4.2$ input='hostname~web:sit'
-bash-4.2$ echo "${input//@(*~|:*)/}"
hostname~web:sit

Comment: Sorry I missed copying `shopt` line in answer. Please try updated answer  now.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in two steps:

```
input=hostname~web:sit

rightpart=${input#*~}   # remove prefix up to "~" (included)
output=${rightpart%:*}  # remove suffix from ":" (included)

echo $output
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using [`cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) wich is available from the [GNU Core Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities):

1. Get all **behind** `~`
2. Get all **before** `:`

```sh
input='hostname~web:sit'
echo "$input" | cut -d '~' -f2 | cut -d ':' -f1
# web
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzOvoLTEVj0jv7gkLzE3ta48NcmqOLNEnSs1OSNfQUkFLK@kUKOQXFqioJuioF6nrqCbZoQkYAUSMPz/HwA)