# Extract string between combination of words and characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to keep the strings between (FROM and as), and (From and newline character).

Input:

```
FROM some_registry as registry1
FROM another_registry
```

Output:

```
some_registry
another_registry
```

Using the following sed command, I can extract the strings. Is there a way to combine the two sed commands?

`sed -e 's/.*FROM \(.*\) as.*/\1/' | sed s/"FROM "//`

Comment: `sed 's/.*From \(.*\) as.*/\1/;s/From //' file`? See https://ideone.com/cjvvaB. Merging into one regex expression is hard here because POSIX regex does not support lazy quantifiers.

Comment: That is because your regex does not match the string you posted in the question (see `From` and `FROM` and `"FROM "`).

Comment: Well, maybe `grep -oP 'FROM\s+\K.*?(?=\s+as\b|$)' file` is a better option? If you have a GNU `grep`, of course.

Comment: From duplicate link, look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25386918/5866580 and when I run it accordingly to shown samples eg: `grep -oP 'FROM\s*\K(?:(?!\s+as).)*' file` it gives me required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging into one regex expression is hard here because POSIX regex does not support lazy quantifiers.

With GNU `sed`, you can pass the command as

```sh
sed 's/.*FROM \(.*\) as.*/\1/;s/FROM //' file
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/cjvvaB).

**However**, if you have a GNU `grep` you can use a bit more precise expression:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='FROM some_registry as registry1
From another_registry'
grep -oP '(?i)\bFROM\s+\K.*?(?=\s+as\b|$)' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/XtDezi). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching ON
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `FROM` - a word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\K` - "forget" all text matched so far
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s+as\b|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with one or more whitespaces and then a whole word `as`, or end of string.