# grep: how to show the next lines after the matched one until a blank line [not possible!]

Tags: dictionary, full-text-search, grep

I have a dictionary (not python dict) consisting of many text files like this:

```
##Berlin                
-capital of Germany         
-3.5 million inhabitants

##Earth           
-planet
```

How can I show one entry of the dictionary with the facts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  grep doesn't have a way of showing a variable amount of context.  You can use -A to show a set number of lines after the match, such as `-A3` to show three lines after a match, but it can't be a variable number of lines.

You could write a quick Perl program to read from the file in "paragraph mode" and then print blocks that match a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

as andy lester pointed out, you can't have grep show a variable amount of context in grep, but a short awk statement might do what you're hoping for.

if your example file were named `file.dict`:

```
awk -v term="earth" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}{if($0 ~ "##"term){loop=1} if($0 ~ /^$/){loop=0} if(loop == 1){print $0}}' *.dict
```

returns:

```
##Earth
-planet
```

just change the variable `term` to the entry you're looking for.

assuming two things:

1. dictionary files have same extension (.dict for example purposes)
2. dictionary files are all in same directory (where command is called)

Comment: is it all files in the folder that you're searching? if so, just change the last word from `*.dict` to `*` and it will search all files in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your grep supports perl regular expressions, you can do it like this:

```
grep -iPzo '(?s)##Berlin.*?\n(\n|$)'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/1331399) for more on this pattern.

You could also do it with GNU sed like this:

```
query=berlin
sed -n "/$query/I"'{ :a; $p; N; /\n$/!ba; p; }'
```

That is, when case-insensitive `$query` is found, print until an empty line is found (`/\n$/`) or the end of file (`$p`).

Output in both cases (minor difference in whitespace):

```
##Berlin
-capital of Germany
-3.5 million inhabitants
```

Comment: @kame: you need to tell sed what files to work on, try appending an asterisk (`*`) to the command.