# Find include guard typos in C++ with gnu coreutils

Tags: c++, grep, include-guards, gnu-coreutils

Below is a typo for a C++ include guard.  Both should read `_MYFILE_H_`.

```
#ifndef _MYFILE_H_
#define _MYFLIE_H_
```

How would you suggest searching a bunch of header files for a typo like this using GNU coreutils (e.g. grep, awk)?

Comment: Save time and #define _MYFLIE_H_ _MYFILE_H_

Comment: I just learned a simpled egrep search won't do: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3717772/

Comment: Neither should read `_MYFILE_H_`. `<g>` Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: I know some awk,grep, due to the lack of my C++ knowledge. I didn't understand what do you want to do...:(

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not sure that those rules appliy to macros, as they specifically mention that these are restrictions on *names*. Essentially, the difference between a name and an identifier is that a name is an identifier which denotes some item. This is why the identifier used to identify a user-defined literal does not count towards this rule. A macro should be the same, as it does not actually exist in the language as an item, it is just a string which gets replaced dumbly in the preprocessor.

Comment: @Agentlien I think it the restriction applies for macros, too. Keep normative constructs like _Bool and _Complex in mind.

Comment: @Agentlien - see 17.6.4.3 [reserved.names] /1: "The C++ standard library reserves the following kinds of names: **macros** ...". Whew, that's a relief!

Comment: @Kay Still, those are keywords ore typedefs. Macros are essentially directives to perform search-and-replace and are performed already in the preprocessor, before names really gain a maeaning.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for the reference. That is something I've been wondering about, since I've seen a lot of macros with these type of names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
{
  if ($1 == "#ifndef") { was_ifdef = 1; def = $2 }
  else if ($1 == "#define" && was_ifdef) 
    { 
      if ($2 != def)   printf("Mismatch in %s: expected %s found %s\n", FILENAME, def, $2);
    }
  else was_ifdef = 0;
}
```

There may be more clever ways to do this, but this is (to me) quite clear and easy.

Note: This will show "false positives" if the file contains something like

```
#ifndef FOO_DEFINED
typedef int foo;
#define FOO_DEFINED 
#endif
```

Comment: I didn't really mean to be that specific.  I actually mentioned awk in the question too, so thanks.

Comment: Ok, removed my comment, and added a note as to "potential false positive".

Comment: This created a few false positives as you said (mainly with macro functions), but I was able to find another typo with your script.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`grep` by itself will not work here because regular expressions are not powerful enough to match the set of strings you're describing.

Specifically, the language of all strings of the form

```
#ifndef X
#define Y
```

Where `X` ≠ `Y` is not a regular language.  You can prove this by using the Myhill-Nerode theorem (since any two strings of the form `#ifndef X` for different choices of `X` fall into different equivalence classes of the distinguishability relation).  As a result, there is no way to write a regular expression that can match strings of this form, and since `grep` uses pure mathematical regular expressions, there is no way to use `grep` to solve this problem.

Sorry for the negative result, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple sed commands could do the trick.

```bsh
for FILENAME in ./*.h; do
     [[ $(sed -n '1p' "$FILENAME" | sed -e 's/#ifndef //') != $(sed -n '2p' "$FILENAME" | sed -e 's/#define //') ]] && echo "$FILENAME"
end
```

Problem with that implementation is, that there may be no copyright header above the guard.

And I'm quite sure that this could be written more concise.