# Regexp for all text between two lines

Tags: regex, grep

I would like match a text like that

```
my  begin line
not useful text that I cannot match because I don't know how it is composed
my end line
```

I'd match all the text above, my problem right now is that I cannot match all the text but just the first line with a regext like that:

```
my begin line\n.*my end line
```

So I am confused, any help ?

Comment: With many regexp implementations you have to provide a modifier to tell it that `.` should match newlines.

Comment: I am using grep, how do that ?

Comment: You can't do it with `grep`, it operates on a line by line basis.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed).

Comment: Can I do with AWK (I don't think so), any other tools ?

Comment: `grep -Pzo '^my begin line\n.*\nmy end line$' your_text_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the lines between two patterns, **excluding** the lines containing the patterns themselves use:

```
sed -n '/my begin line/,/my end line/ {/my begin line/n;/my end line/!p}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sed:

```
sed -n '/my begin line/,/my end line/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned awk in comments:

this gives you all text, (including lines with begin, end pattern)

```
awk '/my  begin line/,/my end line/' file
```

this gives you only lines between the begin/end patterns (without lines with begin, end pattern)

```
awk '/my  begin line/{f=1;next;}/my end line/{f=0}f' file
```