# Grep - using get "Match" to the end of text file with .* not working

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a long text file in ascii. Every so often it will have `Page: #####` in a line of it. I would like to match starting at "Page: 25141" and every single line after that to the end of the document.

Some of the combos I have tried are:

```
grep -E ^["Page: 25141".*] document.txt
grep  "Page: 25141.*" document.txt
grep  "Page: 25141\.\*" document.txt
grep -E "Page: 25141"[.*] document.txt
grep -E "Page: 25141"{.*} document.txt
grep -E {"Page: 25141".*} document.txt
```

Can't get this to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If sed solution is ok for you:

```
sed -n '/Page: 25141/,$p' file
```

The above sed will match all lines between the range starting from the line containing the pattern 'Page 25141, till the end of the file($).

Comment: This will do. Like to learn how it is does with grep using .* to end of document.

Comment: .* is a regex which we use to match a pattern within a line. your requirement is not for a line, its till end of file..

Answer (score 3):

Since `grep` is line-oriented matching multiple lines with a regular expression is not easy. However, the `-A` option will print the context following any matches:

```
grep -A 1000000000 'Page: 25141'
```

You could also do it with `ed` or `sed`:

```
echo '/Page: 25141/,$p' | ed -s filename
```

I almost got it to work with `.*`, based on [nenopera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115) to a similar question. The only problem is that it prints an extra newline at the end:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)Page: 25141.*'
```

Comment: ya, thought of this...but I wanted to do it more efficiently with .*

Answer (score 0):

You can give a thought to awk, which is built for such jobs. `awk 'BEGIN{i=0;} /pattern/ {i=1;} {if(i==1) print}' file` will do you job nicely, and if you want to do more.