# How to find undocumented methods in my code?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am writing documentation for a project and I would like to make sure I did not miss any method. The code is written in Python and I am using PyCharm as an IDE.

Basically, I would need a REGEX to match something like:

```
def method_name(with, parameters):
    someVar = something()
    ...
```

but it should NOT match:

```
def method_name(with, parameters):
    """ The doc string """
    ...
```

I tried using PyCharm's search with REGEX feature with the pattern `):\s*[^"']` so it would match any line after `:` that doesn't start with `"` or `'` after whitespace, but it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: `)` is a special character, use `\)`.  Example: http://regexr.com?35aei

Comment: Can't you do something more reliable by accessing `__doc__`?

Comment: There are modules in the standard library to process python language (tokenizer, syntax trees...). Why using a regex?

Comment: Note that you can **assign** documentation afterwards. `method_name.__doc__ = 'Documentation for method_name'.

Comment: Instead of using a regex, I would suggest running your code through Pylint, it can detect when a docstring is missing.

Comment: You can't use regexps, because Python is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Comment: @F.J pylint would be a solution, but I didn't want to install it just for this project. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know python, but I do know my regex.

And your regex has issues. First of all, as comments have mentioned, you may have to escape the closing parenthesis. Secondly, you don't match the new line following the function declaration. Finally, you look for single or double quotations at the START of a line, yet the start of a line contains whitespace.

I was able to match your sample file with `\):\s*\n\s*["']`. This is a multiline regex. Not all programs are able to match multiline regex. With `grep`, for example, you'd have to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/1968462).

A quick explanation of what this regex matches: it looks for a closing parenthesis followed by a semicolon. Any number of optional whitespace may follow that. Then there should be a new line followed by any number of whitespace (indentation, in this case). Finally, there must be a single or double quote. Note that this matches functions that *do* have comments. You'd want to invert this to find those without.

Comment: thank you. for getting only the methods I added a def in front, like this: `def [a-z_\(\) ,=*]*\):\s*\n\s*[a-z\n]`
this does the job.

Answer (score 6):

You mentioned you were using PyCharm: there is an inspection "Missing, empty, or incorrect docstring" that you can enable and will do that for you.

Note that you can then change the severity for it to show up more or less prominently.

[image]

Comment: this is useful, thank you. but it is a bit too general. I was able to make it report missing documentation by using *Code > Run Inspection by Name* , but it also reported for classes, modules, missing parameters etc, which is too much for what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool called [pydocstyle](https://github.com/PyCQA/pydocstyle) which checks if all classes, functions, etc. have properly formatted docstrings.

Example from the README:

```
$ pydocstyle test.py
test.py:18 in private nested class `meta`:
        D101: Docstring missing
test.py:27 in public function `get_user`:
    D300: Use """triple double quotes""" (found '''-quotes)
test:75 in public function `init_database`:
    D201: No blank lines allowed before function docstring (found 1)
```

I don't know about PyCharm, but pydocstyle can, for example, be integrated in Vim using the [Syntastic plugin](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic).

Comment: Useful for automation.

Answer (score 0):

In case PyCharm is not available, there is a little tool called [ckdoc](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/94df9a8f1c581864171ce5fd2db22b3b) written in **Python 3.5**.

Given one or more *files*, it finds modules, classes and functions without a docstring. It doesn't search in imported built-in or external libraries – it only considers objects defined in files residing in the same folder as the given *file*, or subfolders of that folder.

**Example usage** (after removing some docstrings)

```
> ckdoc/ckdoc.py "ckdoc/ckdoc.py"
ckdoc/ckdoc.py
    module
        ckdoc
    function
        Check.documentable
        anykey_defaultdict.__getitem__
        group_by
        namegetter
    type
        Check
```

There are cases when it doesn't work. One such case is when using Anaconda with [modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/module.html). A possible workaround in that case is to use `ckdoc` from Python shell. Import necessary modules and then call the `check` function.

```
> import ckdoc, main
> ckdoc.check(main)
/tmp/main.py
    module
        main
    function
        main
/tmp/custom_exception.py
    type
        CustomException
    function
        CustomException.__str__
False
```

The `check` function returns `True` if there are no missing docstrings.