# Print all lines between pattern where any line matches second pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have an email log file like this:

```
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: ------------------------------
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Javamail session sending email
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Session properties: 
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    com.hof.email.starttime=20130911120208
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.auth=true
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=60000
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.host=mailserver
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.port=25
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.timeout=60000
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.transport.protocol=smtp
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: From: Support
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: To: Customer
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Subject: Your Report Data
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Message ID: <id>
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: Email sent successfully
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: Javamail session ended
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: ------------------------------
```

What I need to do is print this entire record if the email subject matches a particular string.

That is, what I think I'd like to do is, when `Subject = 'Your Report Data'`, then print all lines between and including the n-1th occurrence of `'------------------------------'` and the 1st occurrence of `'------------------------------'` from the Subject match.

Comment: if the part between the lines is always the same, you can use `grep` with `-A` and `-B`.

Comment: Is subject always line 12 of the block?

Comment: Yes, the structure of the log entry is always the same for every entry.

Comment: As @mnagel indicates, if the format is that fixed (the `----...--` lines are the same distance always from the `Subject:` line), then the "cheesy" way to do it would be: `grep -A 4 -B 12 "INFO:.*Subject: " log.txt` in this case.

Comment: Thank you, @mnagel, this works just fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the part between the lines is always the same, you can use `grep` with `-A` and `-B`.

Answer (score 1):

This only works with `gawk`

```
awk '/Subject: Your Report Data/{printf "%s%s\n",$0,RT}' RS="------------------------------" file
```

Edit: a more complex version, prints correct section

```
cat file
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: ------------------------------
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Javamail session sending email
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Session properties:
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    com.hof.email.starttime=20130911120208
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.auth=true
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=60000
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.host=mailserver
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.port=25
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.timeout=60000
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.transport.protocol=smtp
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: From: Support
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: To: Customer
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Subject: Your Report Data
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Message ID: <id>
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: Email sent successfully
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: Javamail session ended
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: ------------------------------
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Javamail session sending email
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Session properties:
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    com.hof.email.starttime=20130911120208
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.auth=true
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=60000
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.host=mailserver
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.port=25
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.timeout=60000
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.transport.protocol=smtp
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: From: Support
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: To: Customer
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Subject: Error
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Message ID: <id>
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: Email sent successfully
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: Javamail session ended
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: ------------------------------

awk '/---/ {if (p) {for (j=0;j<i;j++) print a[j]};i=0;p=0;delete a;a[i++]=$0} !/---/ {a[i++]=$0} /Your/ {p=1}'
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: ------------------------------
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Javamail session sending email
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Session properties:
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    com.hof.email.starttime=20130911120208
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.auth=true
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=60000
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.host=mailserver
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.port=25
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.smtp.timeout=60000
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO:    mail.transport.protocol=smtp
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: From: Support
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: To: Customer
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Subject: Your Report Data
2013-09-11 12:02:08  INFO: Message ID: <id>
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: Email sent successfully
2013-09-11 12:02:09  INFO: Javamail session ended
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's a GNU grep way to solve this with multiline search. Details on how this works on this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/753731)

```
grep -ozP '(?s)(?<=--\n).*?Subject: Your Report Data.*?(?=\n\N*?--)'
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link and this answer. `-z` is an option that should be remembered :)

Answer (score 0):

For varying number of lines you can use this Ruby code as well:

```
ruby -e 'exp = Regexp.new("^[^\n]+INFO: -{30}$.*?INFO: Subject: #{Regexp.escape(ARGV.shift)}$.*?-{30}$", Regexp::MULTILINE); File.read(ARGV.shift).scan(exp).each{|e| puts e}' "Your Report Data" file
```

It doesn't interpret characters from the subject as regexp chars.