# How to search the content of a file using sed

Tags: shell, command-line, sed, gnu

I tried several commands and read a few tutorials, but none helped. I'm using gnu sed 4.2.2.
I just want to search in a file for:

```
func1(int a)
{
```

I don't know if it is the fact of a newline followed by "{" but it just doesn't work.
A correct command would help and with an explanation even more. Thanks!

Note: After "int a)" I typed enter, but I think stackoverflow doesn't put a newline. I don't want confusion, I just want to search func1(int a)'newline'{.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the string, or replace it? If it's only find, I'd suggest taking a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep.

Comment: Hi Martin, indeed I'm just trying to find. But I don't see how grep could help with the newline followed by "{". If you could give an example of command line I would enjoy because I really really can't figure out.

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed

Comment: Have a look at this for sed: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290/57753

Answer (score 3):

`sed -n '/func1/{N;/func1(int a)\n{/p}'`

Explanation:

```
sed -n '/func1/{                         # look for a line with "func1"
                N                        # append the next line
                /func1(int a)\n{/p       # try to match the whole pattern "func1(int a)\n{"
                                         # and print if matched
               }'
```

With grep it would be for example:

```
grep -Pzo 'func1\(int a\)\n{'
```

but notice that thanks to `-z` the input to `grep` will be one large "line" that includes the newline characters too (that is unless the input contains null characters). Parenthesis have to be escaped in this case because it is a Perl regular expression (`-P`). `-o` makes grep print just the matched pattern.

Comment: +1, and made it general match:  sed -n '/func1/{N;/func1([^)]*)\s*\n\s*{/p}' file