# Extract all text between two directory entries in a file

Tags: regex, bash, macos, grep, pcre

I have a file that documents the structure of several directories. I am trying to print the text for each directory individually. My input file looks like this:

```
$ cat file.txt
/bin:
file_1
file_2
file_3

/sbin:
file_a
file_b
file_c

/usr/local/bin:
doc_a
doc_b
doc_c
```

What I'm trying to do is print a specific section of the file based on user selection:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3=$'\nMake a selection '
select dir in $(grep ':' file.txt;) do
    case $REPLY in
        [0-9]) echo $dir
               # Need something here. Maybe a pcregrep regex?
               # pcregrep '(<= $dir)*(some_fancy_regex)' file.txt
               break;;
    esac
done
```

The user is presented with menu options:

```
1) /bin:
2) /sbin:
3) /usr/local/bin:

Make a selection
```

Suppose the user chooses 2. Currently, this just prints the chosen directory on the screen. I would like to display the directory as well as the files it contains.

```
/sbin:
file_a
file_b
file_c
```

From what I've read it seems like a pcre regex would work here. I barely understand non-pcre style regex. I'm trying to wrap my brain around positive and negative lookahead & lookbehind but I really don't know what I'm doing yet. If someone could help me figure this out I would appreciate it.

1. All directories begin with a `/` and end with `:`
2. File names listed under each directory may contain:

   - `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`,`[0-9]`
   - Literal characters `.` `_` `-` `[`
3. All directory / file structures end with a blank empty line

Comment: A lot of really great answers on this question. It's difficult to say which one 'solved' the problem because at this point, all of the answers have done that.

Comment: Only [one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42875201/1745001) does not involve a shell loop so [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) might help. Also that same one is the only one that will work for all contents of your input file and is portable across all bourne-derived shells on all UNIX systems. The others will only work in a specific shell and/or will fail when your input contains regexp metacharacters or escaped characters or....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done purely in bash 4 in a **single pass** without using any external tool. Here is the script to solve this problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare an associative array
declare -A dirs=()

# loop thru all lines and populate our associate array
# with dir as key and \n separated file names as value
while read -r; do
   [[ -z $REPLY ]] && continue
   if [[ $REPLY == *: ]]; then
      d="$REPLY"
   else
      dirs["$d"]+=$'\n'"$REPLY"
   fi
done < file.txt

# present a menu to customer and print selected dir name with file names
select dir in "${!dirs[@]}"; do
   if [[ -n $dir ]]; then
      printf '%s%s\n' "$dir" "${dirs[$dir]}"
      break
   fi
done
```

**Output:**

```
1) /usr/local/bin:
2) /bin:
3) /sbin:
#? 1
/usr/local/bin:
doc_a
doc_b
doc_c
```

and this:

```
1) /usr/local/bin:
2) /bin:
3) /sbin:
#? 3
/sbin:
file_a
file_b
file_c
```

Comment: Added a sanity check in `select` loop to make sure a valid menu item is selected.

Comment: `select` will put empty value in `dir` variable when an invalid choice is typed by user. If we don't check using above condition then break will stop the select loop.

Comment: I think I basically understand most of this. But could you explain the line `dirs["$d"]+=$'\n'"$REPLY"`?

Comment: `dirs["$d"]+=$'\n'"$REPLY"` is appending a **newline + current line** into array entry with the key as `$d` (we set `d` to a line that ends with colon earlier) We use `$'\n'` notation to prefix each entry with newline.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed and bash:

```
dir="/usr/local/bin:"
sed -n "/${dir//\//\/}/,/^$/{/^$/d;p}" file
```

With bash:

```
dir="/usr/local/bin:"
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line == $dir ]] && switch=1
  [[ $line == "" ]] && switch=0
  [[ $switch == 1 ]] && echo "$line"
done < file
```

Output in both cases:

```
/usr/local/bin:
doc_a
doc_b
doc_c
```

Answer (score 1):

Grep is not to best tool to do this because it is line-oriented; you can't really have grep look at expressions that span multiple lines, except with [some contortion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed/7167115#7167115) – and that `-z` option is not specified by POSIX.

You could do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3=$'\nMake a selection '

mapfile -t opts < <(grep ':' file.txt)

select dir in "${opts[@]}"; do
    sed -n "\@$dir@,/^$/{/^$/q;p}" file.txt
    break
done
```

First, I've changed your menu creation. Notice that you have a spare semicolon within the command substitution and a missing one after it; using grep like this would also break if there are spaces in the directory names. I've thus used `mapfile` to get all the lines containing `:` into an array.

Then, once I know about the directory, I use sed to print "from the directory name on until the next empty line". That would simply be

```
sed -n "/$dir/,/^$/p"
```

but this falls short on multiple fronts. First of all, the directory name can contain slashes, which trips up the `/` delimited addressing. We can use `\%regexp%` instead of `/regexp/`, where `%` can be any character; I've chosen `@`.

Now, we have

```
sed -n "\@$dir@,/^$/p"
```

That's almost there, but prints trailing blank lines; we suppress that by using `{/^$/q;p}` instead of just `p`, which says "if the line is blank, quit, else print it".

Sample output (edited to use a directory name with a space):

```
1) /bin blah:
2) /sbin:
3) /usr/local/bin:

Make a selection 1
/bin blah:
file_1
file_2
file_3
```

---

Remark: Non-GNU seds (like the one found in macOS) might complain about the two commands in curly braces; using `{/^$/q;p;}` instead (extra semicolon) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mistake shell for a text-processing tool, that's what awk is for. All you need are these 4 lines:

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS=') ' '{print NR, $1}' file.txt >&2
printf '\nMake a selection: ' >&2
IFS= read -r rsp
awk -v RS= -v nr="$rsp" 'NR==nr' file.txt

$ ./tst.sh
1) /bin:
2) /sbin:
3) /usr/local/bin:

Make a selection: 2
/sbin:
file_a
file_b
file_c
```