# Dealing with backreference in a sed command inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to make work a sed command inside of a shell script that takes variables while interacting with the user, but I can not make it work because of the backreference I use in it.... some help...?

Script:

```
echo "Origin language?\n"
read ol
echo "\nTarget language?\n"
read tl
echo "\ntmx file name?\n"
read file
```

then at the sed command I have tried these ways:

**1.**

```
sed -r "s/lang=\"$ol\">(.*)$/\1/g" "$file" > ${file}_${ol}.txt
sed -r "s/lang=\"$tl\">(.*)$/\1/g" "$file" > ${file}_${tl}.txt
```

**2.**

```
thisol = "<tuv xml:lang=\"$ol\">(.*)$"
thistl = "<tuv xml:lang=\"$tl\">(.*)$"

sed -r "s/$thisol/\1/g" "$file" > ${file}_${ol}.txt
sed -r "s/$thistg/\1/g" "$file" > ${file}_${tl}.txt
```

**3.**

```
thisol = "<tuv xml:lang=\"$ol\">(.*)$"
thistl = "<tuv xml:lang=\"$tl\">(.*)$"
that = "\\\1"

sed -r "s/$thisol/$that/g" "$file" > ${file}_${ol}.txt
sed -r "s/$thistg/$that/g" "$file" > ${file}_${tl}.txt
```

Comment: You need to escape parentheses of the backreference if you use double quotes. Such as `\(.*\)`.

Comment: That was one of the things I usuccessfuly tried, I tried again though, but no success again....

Comment: Learn what quotes do: `sed -E 's/lang='"$ol"'>(.*)$/\1/g' "$file" > "${file}_${ol}.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment made by @EdMorton I could find the answer to this question, I had to modify a little bit the suggestion made by him, but at the end I realized that this was not what I needed, I should have done it with grep, any way here is the correct code to accomplish what is implied on the question, and the final grep command I used (which I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed))

**sed command:**

```
sed -r '/<tuv xml:lang='\"$ol\"'>/{N;/<seg>/{N;s/<tuv xml:lang='\"$ol\"'>\n\s+<seg>(.*)<\/seg>/\1/}}' "$file.tmx" > "${file}_${ol}.txt"
```

where:

`/<tuv xml:lang='\"$ol\"'>/` the RegEx from the starting line

`{N;/<seg>/` the RegEx from the finishing line

`{N;s/<tuv xml:lang='\"$ol\"'>\n\s+<seg>(.*)<\/seg>` the searched complete RegEx

`/\1/` the backreference to the `(.*)` element

**Grep command:**

```
grep -Pzo "<tuv xml:lang=\"$ol\">\n\s+<seg>(.*)<\/seg>" "$file.tmx" > "${file}_${ol}.txt"
```