# Issues with regex when searching pattern on two lines

Tags: regex, grep

I know this type of search has been address in a few other questions here, but for some reason I can not get it to work in my scenario.
I have a text file that contains something similar to the following patter:

```
some text here done
12345678_123456 226-
more text
some more text here done
12345678_234567 226-
```

I'm trying to find all cases where `done` is followed by `226-` on the next line, with the 16 characters proceeding. I tried `grep -Pzo` and `pcregrep -M` but all return nothing.

I attempted multiple combinations of regex to take in account the 2 lines and the 16 chars in between. This is one of the examples I tried with `grep`:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)done\n.\{16\}226-' filename
```

Related posts:

- [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686147/935627)
- [Regex (grep) for multi-line search needed [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3717772/935627)
- [How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file?](http://How%20can%20I%20search%20for%20a%20multiline%20pattern%20in%20a%20file?)

Comment: Try `grep -Pzo 'done\R.{16}226-' filename` or `grep -Pzo '(?m)done\R.{16}226-$'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not escape `{` and `}` while using `-P` (PCRE) option in `grep`. That escaping is only for BRE.

You can use:

```
grep -ozP 'done\R.{16}226-\R' file

done
12345678_123456 226-
done
12345678_234567 226-
```

`\R` will match any unicode newline character. If you are only dealing with `\n` then you may just use:

```
grep -ozP 'done\n.{16}226-\n' file
```

Comment: You have no idea how much time I wasted messing around with this and never thought of not escaping the `{` `}`.

Comment: @slybloty Escapes are tricky, and work differently in different Regex languages. For Perl, there's a simple rule: "Any escaped punctuation mark is interpreted as a literal; and any non-escaped alpha-numeric character is interpreted as a literal." `grep`, `egrep`, `vim` and others deviate from this basic rule to varying extents; just memorize the specific exceptions if you need to use those.

Answer (score 1):

Generalize it to this `(?m)done$\s+.*226-$`

Because requiring a `\n` after 226- at end of string is a bad thing.
And not requiring a `\n` after 226- is also a bad thing.
Thus, the paradox is solved with `(\n|$)` but why the `\n` at all?

Both problems solved with multiline and  $.

https://regex101.com/r/A33cj5/1