# bash search text between first occurence of pattern1 and last occurence of pattern2

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to get all lines between first occurrence of pattern1 and last occurrence of pattern 2 both the patterns are regex

Example code

```
TEXT
TEXT
[SUN_START]
[SUN_END]

[MON_START]
TEXT
[MON_END]

[TUE_START]
[TUE_END]

[WED_START]
TEXT
[WED_END]
TEXT
TEXT
```

Output that I am expecting is

```
[SUN_START]
[SUN_END]

[MON_START]
TEXT
[MON_END]

[TUE_START]
[TUE_END]

[WED_START]
TEXT
[WED_END]
```

Pattern is XXX_START and XXX_END

What I am got so far is

```
cat /u01/app/oracle/admin/LNOPP1P/config/dbbackup_LNOPP1P.config | sed -n -e '/[[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_START]/,/[[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_END]/p'
```

But this does not keep the line breaks and displays everything together like this

```
[SUN_START]
[SUN_END]
[MON_START]
TEXT
[MON_END]
[TUE_START]
[TUE_END]
[WED_START]
TEXT
[WED_END]
```

I also want to make sure that it only matches the line starts with [[A-Z]_START] and same for END

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk '/_START\]/{p=1} p{a = a $0 ORS}/_END\]/{printf "%s", a; a="";}' file
```

Simple logic:

1. At the first *_START tag, enable p=1. This will discard those lines before the first *_START tag.
2. For every line, append the current line to a local variable.
3. At every *_END tag, print the local variable and empty it.
4. Since we are printing only at the *_END tag, those lines after the last *_END are not printed.

Comment: ^^ Right. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `awk`, using `grep`

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)\[([A-Z]{3})_START\].*\n.*\[\1_END\]' file | sed 's/\x00/\n\n/'
```

you get,

```
[SUN_START]
[SUN_END]

[MON_START]
TEXT
[MON_END]

[TUE_START]
[TUE_END]

[WED_START]
TEXT
[WED_END]
```

*based in [@albfan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/4767343)

Comment: You should mention that uses GNU sed and GNU grep only and that `-P` is "highly experimental" according to the man page..

Comment: I did not know `grep` also supported `-z`. I knew `sed` did, but that does not support non-greedy matching. So I could not make it work. Thanks. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk '/\[..._START\]/{p=1}/\[..._END\]/{print;p=0}p||!NF' file
```

The variable `p` is set when printing is needed.
`!NF` allows to keep blank lines.

Comment: And this would only bring back results where the line starts with [..._START] ?

Comment: Is it simple to invert this selection? select everything but the bit selected by this AWK ?

Comment: That would print blank lines before/after the target area and would not print non-blank lines between an _END..._START within the target area,

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a two-pass approach without saving the contents in memory is the simplest and most robust:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { if (/\[[A-Z]+_START\]/ && !beg) beg=NR; if (/\[[A-Z]+_END\]/) end=NR; next }
    FNR>=beg && FNR<=end
' file file
[SUN_START]
[SUN_END]

[MON_START]
TEXT
[MON_END]

[TUE_START]
[TUE_END]

[WED_START]
TEXT
[WED_END]
```

Consider using `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` for portability across locales.

I just saw you had this comment under a different answer:

```
Is it simple to invert this selection? select everything but the bit selected by this AWK ?
```

and the answer is "of course", just change the condition at the end of the script:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { if (/\[[A-Z]+_START\]/ && !beg) beg=NR; if (/\[[A-Z]+_END\]/) end=NR; next }
    FNR<beg || FNR>end
' file file
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT
```

or keep the original condition but makes it's action "next" and add a default "print" for every other line to hit:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { if (/\[[A-Z]+_START\]/ && !beg) beg=NR; if (/\[[A-Z]+_END\]/) end=NR; next }
    FNR>=beg && FNR<=end { next }
    { print }
' file file
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT
```