# Multiline Bash Regex Match

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I've been reading through tons of threads about this, but none have helped me yet.

This is a sample of my text:

```
    [userId:@"1"
        userName:@""
            userPos:@[@"11006321C", ]
         userDisp:@[@"4200012FD6", ]];



[userId:@"2"
        userName:@""
            userPos:@[@"412520084C",
                     @"7200851", 
                     @"54720021", 
                     ]
        userDisp:@[@"230035FD6", 
                     @"3213456432C0035FD6", 
                     @"1F200538D5", 
                     ]];
```

I'm trying to capture this:

```
userPos:@[@"11006321C", ]
         userDisp:@[@"4200012FD6", ]]
```

and

```
userPos:@[@"412520084C",
                     @"7200851", 
                     @"54720021", 
                     ]
        userDisp:@[@"230035FD6", 
                     @"3213456432C0035FD6", 
                     @"1F200538D5", 
                     ]]
```

(All matches from the text) using regex: `userPos:@\[((?:.\r?\n?)*)\]`

Trying it in bash using:

```
for string in $file # text has been read into this variable
do
    [[ $word =~ $regex ]]
    if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} ]]
    then
        string="${x:+x }${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
        userlist+=("$string")
        echo "$string"
    fi
done
```

To append them to a list.

But this doesn't work since the regex matches noting at all. I know there are different kinds of Regex engines and stuff, and I've tried so many different regexes for this to work in bash, but can't seem to get it to work.

Anyone who could help me capture what I want in bash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex (grep) for multi-line search needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed)

Comment: If you run `osx`, you'll need to run `brew install grep --with-default-names` and reboot your terminal in order to user the `-P` option for `grep`. If you don't want to install new software, you can also use the `awk` solution proposed in the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `userPos:([^;]*)]`.

```
regex="userPos:([^;]*)]"
while [[ $text =~ $regex ]]
do
    string="${x:+x }${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    userlist+=("$string")
    echo "$string"
    text=${text#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}
done
```

`$text` is your text.