# Linux grep expression stop matching until find a windows carriage return character

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Does anyone know a shell command (egrep,grep) to find a match over multiple lines?

Here is part of my data:

```
/id D4333F9F; Fri, 23 Mar 2018 16:12:13 -0300 (-03)^M
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?(Observado)=20[Chamado=202223936]=20-=20?=  =?UTF-8?Q?> Configura=C3=A7=C3=A3o=20DNS?=^M
Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 16:12:13 -0300^M
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8^M
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable^M
Content-Disposition: inline^M
MIME-Version: 1.0^M
```

Inside my bash over here, i have tried to find an expression: `

```
/id D4333F9F.*
```

(Pay attention at the `.*` regular expression **to select everything until the end of the file**)

The command inserted on the window is simulating a `grep` command, but my search stopped at `^M` character

I would like to continue searching until the `MIME-Version` of the header mail (this is an Thunderbird file).

Comment: Sorry, i will edit to go over better

Comment: Do you have a space between `.` and `*` in the regexp? It doesn't look like it in the image, but that's what you put in the question.

Comment: `grep` operates on a single line at a time. The `^M` are all at the end of the lines, they're Windows `CRLF` newlines.

Comment: you can't use `grep` to match across multiple lines.

Comment: Use Control-k to mark formatted text, so it won't be re-wrapped by the SO editor.

Comment: You keep mentioning a "bash", I assume you mean a bash script. You need to post the script you're having trouble with, not an image of a `vim` session.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i've replaced my image to code for i dont do more mistakes

Comment: The replacement doesn't have the line breaks.

Comment: If using grep and the id is not broken by CRLF, just use `/id D4333F9F`. Grep can search anywhere, returns the entire line it found the substring.

Comment: @sln i'm trying to get everything after the id expression, but the windows carriege is stopping my search :-/


I describe the problem using vim editor because i think that the command in the terminal linux will not help us.:


minossi@CW000683:~/.thunderbird/9jmr3uzb.default$ egrep -rn "id D4333F9F.*" ~/.thunderbird/*.default/ImapMail/imap*/INBOX*/[Observado]*

Comment: If you're trying to get to the end of file, unless grep has slurp capability, but wouldn't be grep then. If running from a script, don't use grep. But if you have to, then find where the first grep find is. Then catenate with a separate grep `.+` all the lines after.

Comment: How can i change this topic as solved? I had never imagined that grep cant across multiple lines :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, lets consider this file:

```
$ cat file
before
/id D4333F9F 1234
another line
last line in file
```

The problem that you are running into is not `^M`.  It is that standard `grep` processes only one line at a time.

#### Using sed

To get everything from the line containing `/id D4333F9F` to the end of the file,  there are several standard tools that you can use.  For example, try `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/\/id D4333F9F/,$ p' file
/id D4333F9F 1234
another line
last line in file
```

Here `/\/id D4333F9F/,$ p` tells sed to print any lines starting with a line matching `/id D4333F9F` and ending with the last line (`$`).

#### Using awk

Try `awk`:

```
$ awk '/\/id D4333F9F/{f=1} f' file
/id D4333F9F 1234
another line
last line in file
```

Here, `/\/id D4333F9F/{f=1}` tells awk to set the variable `f` to one when the first line that matches `/id D4333F9F` is found.  The last `f` is shorthand that tells awk to print if `f` is true (meaning nonempty or nonzero).

#### Using grep with GNU extensions

Lastly, if your `grep` has the `-P` extension (this requires GNU grep), then try:

```
$ grep -ozP '(?s)/id D4333F9F.*' file
/id D4333F9F 1234
another line
last line in file
```

This grep code is explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/3030305).