# Regex ignoring linebreaks and "page layout"

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have an assortment of searchable PDF files and I often search particular patterns in all of them simultaneously, using the `pdfgrep` command. My regex knowledge is somewhat limited and I'm not sure how to work around linebreaks and page layout.

For example, I would like to find the pattern `"ignor.{0,10}layout"` in each example below:

```
This is a rather difficult     You see, I would like to ignore
task that I am trying to       page layout and still find the
achieve.                       pattern I am looking for.
```

```
This is a rather difficult     This is because I would like to ig-
task that I am trying to       nore page layout and still find the
achieve.                       pattern I am looking for.
```

In both examples, I would like the first two lines to be reported by

```
pdfgrep -n "ignor.{0,10}layout" *
```

but it fails to do so because:

- there is a linebreak in the middle.
- in the first example, there are more than 10 characters between `ignor` and `layout`.
- in the second example, `ignor` is cut in half.

Is there a regex that would solve this problem entirely?

Comment: The lines on the left side are definitely part of my problem, if that was your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdfgrep` does not have the `-z` flag that would be necessary to interpret newlines as zero-bytes. You can use a workaround with `pdftotext`, that allows to convert it to text and stream this to STDOUT, where you can pipe a regular `grep` call:

```
pdftotext SPECIFIC-FILE.pdf - | grep -Pzo "(?s)YOUR\s+QUERY"
```

This makes it impossible to use globbing efficiently, but you can at least iterate the glob:

```
for pdf in *.pdf; do echo -n "$pdf:"; pdftotext "$pdf" - | grep -Pzo "(?s)YOUR\s+QUERY"; done
```

Please note that if you want to match whitespaces, you almost always will want to use `\s+` which matches also newlines, when `-z` is enabled. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/10484131) for an explanation of the flags.

Comment: `-z` would translate `"word1\nword2"` into `"word1word2"` instead of `"word1 word2"`, would it not? Also I believe that this solution doesn't spot `ignor` in the second example?

Comment: I think it's almost exactly what I need though, I'm trying to work on what you submitted. All I need is to replace all `-` by nothing and all linebreaks by spaces. And maybe show a little more than just the pattern because the `.txt` file has only 1 line, so the only way to locate the pattern is to know the characters before and the characters after.

Comment: `for pdf in *.pdf; do echo -n "$pdf:"; pdftotext "$pdf" - | sed -z 's/-//g;s/\n//g' | grep -Po ".{0,20}ignor.{0,10}layout.{0,20}"; echo ""; done` solved my problem, thank you very much!