# grep string with special characters in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

my file contains:

```
/*uid:68160*/\n            SELECT
/*uid:68160*/SELECT
```

I tried with below:

```
grep -vF "/[*]uid::[[:digit:]][*]/SELECT"
```

which is helping to removed 2nd line.
How to remove 1st line by grep 
also tried:

```
grep -vF "/[*]uid::[[:digit:]][*]/\n            SELECT"
```

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: Multiline regexp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed

Comment: Worked:   grep -Ev '/[*]uid:[[:digit:]]+[*]/[\]n            SELECT'

Comment: @AbhijitShinde : Why did you use `-F`? This option means (from the man-page) _Interpret PATTERN as a list of  **fixed**  strings  (instead  of  regular  expressions)_

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a *literal* text like that,

```
s='/*uid:68160*/\n            SELECT
/*uid:68160*/SELECT
Text'
```

and you want to remove lines 1 and 2, you may use

```
 grep -Ev '/[*]uid:[[:digit:]]+[*]/(\\n *)?SELECT'
```

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/7tdoDq)

**Details**

- `-Ev` - `E` enables POSIX ERE and `v` will negate the result
- `/[*]uid:[[:digit:]]+[*]/(\\n *)?SELECT` - matches

  - `/[*]uid:` - a `/*uid:` string
  - `[[:digit:]]+` - 1+ digits
  - `[*]/` - a `*/` string
  - `(\\n *)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `\n` two-char combination and then any 0 or more spaces
  - `SELECT`  - a string