# Regex to match / output yml documents in logfile containtaining specific string

Tags: regex

I have a logfile I'm tailing and want to output only those yaml documents (separated by `---`) containing a specific string (specific domain in hostname).

**Example logfile contents:**

(focus on the `hostname`)

```yaml
---
event: outgoing HTTP response
timestamp: 2021-10-06T08:15:28.212Z
remoteAddress: "1.2.3.4"
hostname: a.b.c.domain.com
statusCode: 200
headers:
  content-length: 524
  etc: ...
body: "blabla (can be multiline and can contain anything)"
---
event: outgoing HTTP response
timestamp: 2021-10-06T08:15:28.212Z
remoteAddress: "1.2.3.4"
hostname: a.b.c.different.com
statusCode: 200
headers:
  content-length: 524
  etc: ...
body: "blabla (can be multiline and can contain anything)"
---
event: outgoing HTTP response
timestamp: 2021-10-06T08:15:28.212Z
remoteAddress: "1.2.3.4"
hostname: 1.2.3.domain.com
statusCode: 200
headers:
  content-length: 524
  etc: ...
body: "blabla (can be multiline and can contain anything)"
```

expected output:

```yaml
---
event: outgoing HTTP response
timestamp: 2021-10-06T08:15:28.212Z
remoteAddress: "1.2.3.4"
hostname: a.b.c.domain.com
statusCode: 200
headers:
  content-length: 524
  etc: ...
body: "blabla (can be multiline and can contain anything)"
---
event: outgoing HTTP response
timestamp: 2021-10-06T08:15:28.212Z
remoteAddress: "1.2.3.4"
hostname: 1.2.3.domain.com
statusCode: 200
headers:
  content-length: 524
  etc: ...
body: "blabla (can be multiline and can contain anything)"
```

I cannot get my head around the regex I need. Matching every document (regardless of what's inside) I'm doing this:

```
/---\n[\s\S]+?(?=\n---|$)/g
```

see also: https://regex101.com/r/a8zKSz/2

However I cannot figure out how to only output those documents matching hostname with the domain `domain.com` (regex for the match within could be e.g. `/hostname: .*?domain\.com/`

I like to end up having a sed / perl or any other "oneliner" applicable on a "default linux OS". `tail -F logfile.log | oneliner` But getting the regex is the first step.

Any hints or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have to say that regex are not the proper tool for this. If your input is Yaml, then use a tool made specially for Yaml.

For example, using [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq), this can be done very easily:

```
cat example | yq eval 'select(.hostname | test ".domain.com")' -
```

Equivalently, for JSON inputs, there is [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

**Regex solution**

Still, this is an interesting challenge, and might be cases where regexes are the most appropriate tool for the job. [Here is a version](https://regex101.com/r/abGZry/1) that works.

Below, I wrote the pattern with added spacing, and split the regex on 4 lines to make it easier to read.

```
---\n
( (?!---|hostname:) [^\n]+? (\n|$) )*
hostname:[^\n]+.domain.com (\n|$)
( (?!---|hostname:) [^\n]+? (\n|$) )*
(?=---|$)
```

The principle here is to write the pattern as an explicit state machine. A regex always describe a state machine, but we tend not to thing about it; but here, we want to make this very obvious.

1. In the initial state, we look for a "yaml document start" marker (that is `---\n`). When find such a line, we move to state #2.
2. In state #2, we capture input lines (exactly one line at a time). We however refuse to capture a line that starts with 'hostname:' (which will force a transition to state #3) nor a line that starts with `---` (which will force the engine to backtrack on step #1).
3. In State #3, we capture a single line, starting with `hostname:`, but only if the rest of the line matches the expected domain. If such a line is captured, then we jump to state #4. If we can't match the line, then the engine can't continue (because of the negative lookahead in step #2) and will therefore backtrack on step #1).
4. In State #4, we continue capturing input lines, until we reach the end of that document (that is, until we reach the next line matching '---\n').

**Perl solution**

Given that neither the `yq` solution nor the `regex` solution is viable in your situation, here is yet another approach, this time using perl (no external module required).

Once again, I format the code so that it is easier to understand, but this can easily be reduced to a single line.

```
perl -ne '
    if ($_ =~ /^---$/) {
        $match = 0;
        $doc = $_;
    } elsif ($match) {
        print($_);
    } else {
        $doc .= $_;
        if ($_ =~ /^hostname: [^\n]*\.domain\.com$/) {
            print($doc);
            $match = 1;
        }
    }
'
```

Comment: Hey @jwatkins - thx a lot. The yq version is indeed very simple and elegant. And getting that answer from the repo owner makes it even nicer ;-) This I could test in my dev environment but cannot use in prod.

I'm still trying to make the regex work on a tail -F with grep. I will accept your answer once tested successfully tomorrow.

Thx again - also very nice explanation for the regex.

Comment: I doubt it will work using `tail -F ... | grep ...`.

By default, `grep` works one line at a time, so it is not possible to perform multiline matches. This behaviour can be change in GNU's `grep` using the `-zo` arguments (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed/7167115#7167115) for explanations), but enabling this option makes `grep` wait for stdin to close before passing the input to the Regex library.

That means you can't process streaming content using this strategy.

Comment: The yq version works with stream (`tail -F`) but does not output the last document. When `cat file.log` I get everything but order is reversed.
Using the regex with grep `cat logtest.log | grep -Pzo -- '---\n((?!---|hostname:)[^\n]+?(\n|$))+hostname:[^\n]+.domain\.com(\n|$)((?!---|hostname:)[^\n]+?(\n|$))+(?=---|$)'` works with a static file but does not with a stream (as you wrote in the comment). The Perl version works with stream/tail and cat but does also not output the last document.

I have a modified perl version in my next comment which corrects this.

Comment: `tail -F logtest.log | perl -ne '
    $doc .= $_;
    if ($_ =~ /^---$/) {
        $match = 0;
        $doc = $_;
    } elsif ($_ =~ /^hostname: [^\n]*\.domain\.com$/) {
        $match = 1;
    }
    if ($match) {
        print($doc);
        $doc = "";
    }'`

Comment: You are right... assuming a streaming input, my initial perl suggestion would block until a new document comes in before outputting a matching document. I updated the code in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution without regex in python.
Consider your text in `test.log`

```
f=open('test.log','r')
contents=f.read().split('---')
for content in contents:
    if content:
        if '.domain.com' in content.splitlines()[4]:
            print(content)
```