# How to list all methods in a Java class with regex

Tags: java, regex

is there any way to search all methods in Java class with regex?

Comment: of course it is possible even it would be a complex regex. but what are you trying to achieve? you can get the list of methods with java reflection much more easily.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a Java code file or what? Regex certainly is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Um, I am really impressed. It's a first time I see regex used as reflection tool.

Comment: You are probably looking for AspectJ Pointcut expressions: http://guptavikas.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/aspectj-pointcut-expressions/

Comment: I cannot compile the class due to some data not ready yet, that's why I cannot use java reflection.

Comment: @user2621732 it's not clear that regex is the best solution to your problem. If you want more useful help please explain the actual underlying problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(public|protected|private|static|\s) +[\w\<\>\[\]]+\s+(\w+) *\([^\)]*\) *(\{?|[^;])
```

With this you can, but search before ask, because i only have used the search to find this answer ^^.

Comment: That would not account for comments or strings. And if you copied that expression from somewhere, give the original author credit by linking to the source.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633/regex-that-will-match-a-java-method-declaration?rq=1 This is the link where this is discused. Thanks to Georgios Gousios.

Comment: I still got 
`
        else if (plane == REFLECT_PLANE_XZ)`
in the results. Any idea?

Comment: try to use only the first part oh the exreg, altaugh is a little suspicious that the string that you paste validate the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for reflection - see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html) tutorial for help. Only through reflection can you access information about loaded classes - unless you're thinking of loading in the `.java` file and analyzing its text.